# Четверть миллиона вопросов в русскоязычной базе знаний!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Очередной рубеж пройден вместе!

[image]

## Поздравляю всех нас!

Уважаемые участники сообщества Stack Overflow на русском, большое вам спасибо, за вашу помощь коллегам. Благодаря вам, программирование шаг за шагом становится доступнее русскоязычным людям.

Comment: Где-то через полгода должны выйти на [пятое место](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions). Но при текущих темпах выше третьего не быть никогда.

Comment: @älёxölüt У меня есть мечта — обойти математиков =) Думаю, однажды у нас получится!

Comment: Математиков сложно обойти, они придумают какую-нибудь формулу, по которой всегда будут впереди!

Comment: Поздравляю! Надеюсь, что наступит день, когда в русскоязычной базе знаний будет **1000 000** вопросов!

Comment: И какой же вопрос номер 250000? :)

Comment: @Harry Мне кажется, что [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/935170/6)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky У меня есть предложение на этот вопрос начать конкурс, чтобы все знали :)

Comment: Это действительно очень значимое событие. В сравнении с другими сайтами SE, которые намного дольше работают (кроме ensSO), статистика ruSO действительно радует и восхищает. Появляется спортивное желание помочь догнать и перегнать впереди стоящих.

Comment: а сколько из них отвеченных? )

Comment: @xhr [На сегодня, чуть менее 50 тысяч](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered).

Comment: @xhr Скорее, [чуть менее 70 тысяч](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest).