# Создадим свободную базу знаний на русском языке, вместе!

Tags: поддержка

Миссия Stack Overflow — собрать библиотеку ответов на все возможные прикладные вопросы по программированию. Создаваемая общими силами библиотека доступна всем: в 99% случаев ваш вопрос уже кто-то задал на Stack Overflow. Все, что вам нужно — воспользоваться готовым решением совершенно бесплатно.

Не все хотят того, чего и мы. Кто-то вместо знаний создает [спамо подобные сайты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6) с машинными переводами из англоязычного сообщества, которые усложняют поиск ответов и получение новых знаний. Проблема начинает набирать обороты. Например, те, кто вчера говорил — «Ой, да я на английском ищу! Русскоязычная база знаний — не мое дело», сегодня ругают Google, который показывает им спам-сайты вне зависимости от того, какой язык они используют для запроса.

На мой взгляд, мы можем избавиться от спамоподобного содержимого в поисковой выдаче, начав работать над базой знаний вместе с удвоенной силой.

#### Делитесь знаниями с сообществом

Причина наличия машинных переводов в поисковой выдаче не в алгоритмах поисковиков, а в том, что мы не делится своими знаниями публично. Поисковики лишь выбирают из существующего. Как только появится содержимое на русском языке, созданное сообществом, с большой вероятностью, машинные переводы пропадут из поисковой выдачи.

Один из эффективных способов накопления знаний — делиться с коллегами заметками в [формате вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Когда вы сталкиваетесь с проблемой, законспектируйте проблему и её решения, выложите ваши заметки в общий доступ на сайте. В будущем, когда вы повторно столкнетесь с той же проблемой, найти решение будет просто. Кроме того, многие коллеги также смогут воспользоваться предложенным вами решением.

#### Рассказывайте о сайте коллегам

Мы видим, что в природе не бывает пустоты: мы либо создаем нашу свободную базу знаний и русскоязычное сообщество, либо довольствоваться машинными переводами с английского языка, преодолевая сопутствующие трудности каждый сам по себе без какой–либо поддержки. Когда вы в следующий раз услышите про «английский язык в поисковом запросе», пожалуйста, обязательно поясните коллеге, какой он делает выбор.

Расскажите коллеге [о сайте](/tour), [миссии проекта](/help/manifesto), [предложите задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Успех русскоязычного сообщества зависит от ваших рекомендаций. Если мы сможем вовлечь наших коллег в создание сводной базы знаний на русском языке, она получится по настоящему всеобъемлющей, покрывающий каждый прикладной вопрос по программированию.

#### Задавайте вопросы, которых еще нет на сайте

Если на ваш запрос к поисковику в выдаче есть сайты с машинным переводом, но нет Stack Overflow на русском, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш вопрос в русскоязычном сообществе. Если у вас есть время, [переведите лучший на ваш взгляд ответ с английского языка на русский](/help/translate-from-english). Такой подход поможет создавать больше полезных знаний на русском языке. Пожалуйста, задавайте каждый вопрос, для которого вы встретите машинные переводы, вне зависимости, знаете ли вы ответ или нет. Будет вопрос, появятся и ответы.

Comment: Верно ли, что вопрос стоит переименовать в "Предлагаю бороться с сайтами автопереводов enSO путем пиара ruSO среди знакомых" ?

Comment: Опять эта борьба с ветряными мельницами.

Comment: @Suvitruf `Сражаться  с ветряными мельницами - Бороться с воображаемыми врагами; бесцельно тратя силы`

Как мне кажется, qaru и подобные сайты - это не воображаемые враги, мне не нравится что они на первых позициях в выдаче, а оригинального вопроса вообще может не быть. Это как минимум неудобно. Но эффективность таких(описанных выше) способов борьбы с этими сайтами - вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @AntonSorokin На мой взгляд, это самые эффективные способы. Особенно приобщение коллег к публикации знаний в открытый доступ. Мы не будем соревноваться с сайтами с машинным переводом в количестве контента. Отличительная особенность нашего сообщества в доброте к коллегами и качественном содержимом. Остальное придет со временем.

Comment: @AntonSorokin я имел ввиду, по большей части, что они пытаются бороться со следствием, а не причиной. Да и предпосылка "клепайте контент, т.к. нас автопереводы обгоняют" - такое себе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky время покажет эффективность. Опять же с другой стороны - "расскажите о SO всем" - тоже хороший позыв для увеличения базы пользователей.

Comment: @Suvitruf так что делать? Предложите способ решения проблемы, если знаете как ее правильно решать.

Comment: @AntonSorokin движок улучшить, чтоб поисковики норм парсили контент, для начала.

Comment: @Suvitruf Ну, это достаточно большие изменения. Надо доносить это все до англо администрации. Интересно, они вообще видят эту проблему?(англоговорящим то не видно сайтов с автопереводами)
P.S. Даже не так - мне кажется, что даже если они и знают про эту проблему, им немножко все равно, что бы ради этого переделывать движок.

Comment: @AntonSorokin видят, но эта проблема, в целом, только для локализованных сайтов актуальна. Поэтому, с их стороны никакой работы в этом плане ждать не приходится.

Comment: @Suvitruf  Создается впечатление, что вы не прочитали публикацию. Проблема не в индексации SO. Проблема в отсутствии знаний на русском языке. Будет не машинные переводы, будет что–то другое, до тех пор пока русскоязычное сообщество не заполнит пустоту. Русскоязычному сообществу и базе знаний быть. Но как она будет выглядеть, решается сейчас.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тогда может лучше убрать из вопроса эту часть, иначе оно производит неверное впечатление?

Comment: Имхо, пополнение базы никак не изменит ситуации с "сайтами-автопереводами". Поэтому эту часть можно вообще удалить из поста.

Comment: попахивает коммунизмом

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Изменит. Мы соберем примеры вопросов на английском, на русском и машинный перевод, отправим все это в Google/Яндекс, чтобы исправляли. Всем поисковикам необходим конкретный пример страниц и запросов. При этом поисковики явно говорят, что они против генерированных текстов. Будут пример, будет о чем говорить с поддержкой поисковиков.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я уверен на 100% что конкретно с машинным переводом проблемы мы не решим. Поисковики могут говорить что угодно, но сайты с машинным перевод как жили так и будут жить. Просто я по своему опыту знаю что это такое.....

Comment: _с удвоенной силой_, _совершенно бесплатно_ - угу... А нельзя ли наоборот: сил прикладывать меньше (или хотя бы столько же), но за вознаграждение?

Comment: _свободную базу знаний_ - ой ли? То-то с ресурса уже поуходил народ, несогласный со _свободой_.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Содержимое сайта распространяется под лицензией CC-BY-SA 3.0. Участие на сайте добровольное: вы сами для себя решаете, хотите ли вы делиться знаниями с сообществом или нет.

Comment: Николай, в чём суть этих регулярных призывов к действиям? Вопрос был закрыт как дубликат существующего, и было бы неплохо при единоличном переоткрытии вопроса сделать поясняющую правку, как этого просят от рядовых участников.

Comment: @älёxölüt Это совершенно разные публикации с разной мотивацией позади и разным смыслом. Тот вопрос был в рамках исследования ассоциаций вопросов между сайтами. Ответы в нем соответствующие. Этот вызван проблемой машинно переведенного содержимого.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky предпосылки может и разные, а суть (решение), имхо, одна — наполняйте базу вопросов/ответов. На основном сайте, если решения одинаковые, вопросы предлагают закрывать как дубликаты.

Comment: @älёxölüt Публикации совершенно разные. Прочитайте их, пожалуйста, внимательно. По вашей логике, на основном сайте можно все вопросы назначить дубликатами к одному, так как они все о программировании и решаются написанием программного кода.

Comment: Странно, что вы так интерпретировали «мою логику». Но, давайте представим следующую «проблему», назовём её — [«обойти математиков»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8572/?cb=1#comment35417_8572), там будет сказано примерно следующее: «Наполняйте базу, делитесь с коллегами и мы в топе». Не дубликат?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky часть "SA" в лицензии автоматически делает всё несвободным

Comment: Как так получается, что машинный перевод лучше индексируется? Кто-нибудь проводил исследование на эту тему?

Comment: @vp_arth вопрос не в качестве индексации. вопрос в наличии машинного перевода + отсутствиии ручного для многих топовых вопросов. Если бы был ручной для большого количества вопросов - на поисковики можно было бы давить "вот тут качественный ручной перевод, а тут - машинный, опустите его!". А сейчас - давить нечем, нельзя просто взять и попросить выбросить из индекса сайт, за то, что в нем есть контент, если у нас аналогичного более качественного контента нет.

Comment: @PashaPash это [не всегда так](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48877707#48877707)

Answer (score 21):

Это очень сложная задача, практически нереализуемая на платформе Stack Exchange. Оригинальный сайт Stack Overflow, к примеру, с ней так и не справился. Просто потому что практически никого из посетителей эта цель не волнует ни в малейшей степени.

Тех, кто задает вопросы, интересует не создание базы знаний, а решение собственных сиюминутных проблем, вызванных зачастую ленью, самомнением, неумением логически мыслить, спешкой. Все это приправлено неспособностью даже внятно сформулировать проблему.

Теми, кто отвечает на вопросы, движет по большей части удовлетворение собственного эго, страсть к виртуальным знакам отличия (активно поощряемая системой) и какое-то болезненное стремление удовлетворить каприз спрашивающего любой ценой.

То есть, сами участники воспринимают SO не как базу знаний, а скорее как конвейер по решению сиюминутных проблем.

Также, весьма важной составляющей качественной базы знаний является своевременное обновление информации, для того, чтобы с таким трудом кропотливо собранная информация не устаревала через 2-3 года. С этим у сайтов на площадке SE полный провал. Вместо обновления и дополнения уже существующей базы знаний в нее добавляется еще одна пара вопрос-ответ, что размывает её, делает сложным поиск и вместо единой базы  качественных ответов в итоге получается размазанная тонким слоем череда повторяющихся решений для частных случаев.

Также, для создания качественного контента необходим некий механизм арбитража. Чтобы отбрасывать совсем уж мусорный контент. Отсутствие такого механизма является принципиальной позицией администрации, отдавая аудит контента во власть толпы. Ни к чему хорошему это не приводит.

Лучше всего проиллюстрировать вышесказанное на примере. Вот хорошая аналогия:

> [*Imagine Wikipedia with several hundred articles on the New York city. And one that Google links first is a copy-pasted article from Encyclopedia Britannica, 1913, just because of its age. And every other day several kids from the elementary school start a new one. To impress other kids with their contribution.*](https://phpdelusions.net/)
>
> Представьте себе Википедию, в которой есть несколько сотен статей про Санкт-Петербург. И первая в поисковой выдаче гугла - это перепечатка из энциклопедии Брокгауза и Эфрона, просто потому что она появилась раньше всех. Причем почти каждый день очередной школьник начинает новую статью про Санкт-Петербург, чтобы поразить одноклассников глубиной своих знаний.

Это, конечно, преувеличенное и довольно злое сравнение, но оно показывает пропасть, которая лежит между настоящей базой знаний и Stack Overflow. Который, в противоположность Википедии (и вопреки декларациям), по факту представляет из себя  конвейер по решению сиюминутных, по большей части плохо сформулированных проблем. В котором пресловутая база составляется исключительно в качестве побочного эффекта и работает только для самых тривиальных и прямолинейных вопросов.

Comment: "некий механизм арбитража" а можете поподробнее расписать, в каком виде вы такой механизм себе представляете? Можно даже отдельным тредом. P.S. с возвращением

Comment: @Suvitruf, вообще вводили и называли [`triage`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) Но у нас похоже не подключили еще

Comment: @Grundy так это и есть отдание "контента во власть толпы". Просто лишний шаг, который могут выполнять малореповые участники.

Comment: Не в рекламу сказано, на пикабу есть модераторы, которые отправляют весь контент, который не подходит под правила политики общества в отдельное место, где трудно найти его обычным обывателям. Думаю, на SO подошла бы такая сортировка. Те же модераторы - каста общества, которая на протяжении долго времени была очень активна здесь, и буквально, жила здесь.

Comment: @KeyJibo ну, текущие модераторы у нас вроде как тоже из народа, но что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Отличный анализ. А предложения (тезисы), каким образом из существующего материала можно сделать настоящую базу знаний будут?

Comment: Эти все проблемы обсуждаются постоянно, все всё знают. К чему ваш текст не понимаю.

Answer (score 11):

Вопрос создания базы знаний на площадке ruSO если и волнует, то только узкий круг энтузиастов. Для остальных это скорее просто площадка для обмена опытом и помощи между коллегами. Притом и то и другое, к сожалению, не всегда взаимно, но об этом уже отдельный разговор.

Ситуация осложняется ещё и тем, что, при всём уважении, ruSO по ряду объективных причин не обладает таким охватом как enSO ни по аудитории, ни по технологиям. Во всяком случае пока.

Как известно, "Свято место пусто не бывает". Поэтому, чему здесь удивляться? Тем более, что задающим как правило безразлично, где именно они получат ответ на свой вопрос.

Отвечающих предлагаемая идея также вряд ли будет всерьёз мотивировать. Ведь даже от репутации и поощрительных знаков за ответы в реальной жизни опять же по большей части никому ни холодно, ни жарко.

Поэтому подобные призывы, ИМХО, это "глас вопиющего в пустыне", потому что всем по большому счёту всё равно.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь в том, что от репутации и поощрительных знаков за ответы в реальной жизни по большей части никому ни холодно, ни жарко. Это часть личного бренда и это дополнительный фактор привлекательности для работодателей. Впрочем, если бы всё-таки запустили [историю разработчика](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2400/204271) и смогли интегрироваться с площадками типа hh.ru и fl.ru, толку было бы больше.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, слова "по большей части" я сказал не случайно. Знаки и репутация на самом деле могут послужить в первую очередь для удовлетворения своего эго. Да и чтобы профиль стал частью личного бренда свои достижения в сообществе ещё нужно суметь правильно подать. А, насчёт карьерных разделов сайта я полностью с Вами согласен. Если бы на ruSO были хотя бы developer store и jobs эффективность была бы на порядок больше.