# Меньше спама, больше полезных знаний о программировании: как бороться с машинными переводами в поисковой выдаче

Tags: поддержка, перевод-содержимого

Машинные переводы забивают поисковую выдачу, затрудняя получение нужной информации, [вне зависимости от языка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8606/6), который мы используем для поиска. [Когда мы вместе обсуждали вопрос автопереводов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/6), несколько участников подчеркнули, что изредка машинные переводы, как и статьи на неизвестном иностранном языке, могут быть полезны — в случае, когда совсем ничего другого нет.

На мой взгляд, напрашивается вывод: *отсутствие знаний на русском языке — основная причина появления машинных переводов и ключ к их исчезновению из поисковой выдачи.*

### Как бороться с машинными переводами в поисковой выдаче?

#### 1. Задавайте вопросы, которых еще нет на сайте

Если на ваш запрос к поисковику в выдаче есть сайты с машинным переводом, но нет Stack Overflow на русском, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш вопрос в русскоязычном сообществе. Если у вас есть время, переведите лучший на ваш взгляд ответ с английского языка на русский. Пожалуйста, задавайте каждый вопрос, для которого вы встретите машинные переводы, вне зависимости, знаете ли вы ответ или нет. Такой подход создаст больше полезных знаний на русском языке.

#### 2. Как только вы задали вопрос, уведомите поисковик

Поисковики явно пишут, что они [против автоматически созданного содержимого](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769):

> Избегайте следующих приемов:
>
> - [Автоматически созданное содержимое](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306).
> - [Партнерские программы](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356).
> - [Скопированное содержимое](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175?visit_id=636849716801769871-2043523128&rd=2#thin-content).
> - …

Сообщите поисковику, что вы нашли созданный алгоритмами текст. Для этого заполните [форму](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreportform?hl=ru):

- *Адрес конкретной веб-страницы, где обнаружено нарушение* — страница на сайте с машинным переводом.
- *Точный запрос, с помощью которого была обнаружена проблема* — поисковый запрос, по которому вы наткнулись на машинный перевод.
- *Дополнительная информация* — комментарий в свободной форме о том, что это автоматически созданное содержимое, дополнив ссылкой на ваш вопрос и вопрос на английском. Например, комментарий может выглядеть так

  > Сайт содержит только автоперевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/.../. Замените, пожалуйста, ссылку в выдаче на страницу созданную человеком https:/ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/.../.

Если на Stack Overflow на русском уже есть вопрос, но в поисковой выдаче машинный перевод появляется выше, пожалуйста, проделайте аналогичные шаги, указав в комментарии, что по запросу находится автоматически созданное содержимое, а сайты, созданные людьми — нет.

[Похожий интерфейс](https://yandex.ru/support/search/troubleshooting/delspam.html) есть у Яндекса (необходимо выбрать пункт «Поисковый спам» или «Другое»).

#### Общие проблемы решаются сообща

Создать базу знаний на русском языке, как и избавиться от сомнительного содержимого в поисковой выдаче мы сможем только вместе. Сообществу нужна ваша помощь и помощь ваших неравнодушных коллег: пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы, которых еще нет на сайте, вовлекайте в участие ваших коллег!

Comment: А есть примеры из вашей практики, когда такие репорты помогали? По опыту работы с Google могу сказать, что их сапорт весьма плох. И, насколько я понял из беседы в чате, вы собирались от лица компании с Google разговаривать. Маловероятно, что они будут что-то в выдаче менять по репортам обычных пользователей.

Comment: В фразе "опубликуйте ваш вопрос в русскоязычном сообществе" нужно конкретизировать _где_ опубликовывать. На сайте? На мете? В чате? В форме обратной связи?

Comment: Текст подзаголовков оторван от смысла абзацев. "задали (на so) (новый) вопрос - уведомьте поисковик (о чём?)" - это в заголовке, при этом абзац начинается "уведомьте поисковик о том, что нашли созданный алгоритмами текст". Ну и какой алгоритмами автоперевода может быть текст у свежесозданного вопроса? в первом подзаголовке возможно стоит уточнить: в заголовке "задавайте (на so?) вопросы, которых нет на сайте" - и тут же "если нашёлся автогенерённый контент". Видимо следует уточнить алгоритм: искал ответ на so встроенным поиском, не нашёл, полез в поисковик, нашёл автоперевод на другом сайте.

Comment: @Nicolas Не пойму, это у вас вопрос или ответ?

Comment: @Kromster это совет по набиранию кармы (напоролся на автоперевод -> значит топик нужен как минимум тебе -> перевод, плюсы) + конкретные меры по борьбе с переводами (у гугла автоперевод явно включен в список плохого контента).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky у яндекса кнопка "пожаловаться" есть прямо в интерфейсе поиска, в треугольнике для каждого результата

Comment: Для того, чтобы  избавиться от сомнительного содержимого в поисковой выдаче, в первую очередь надо  избавиться от сомнительного содержимого на русском SO. До тех пор, пока большинство участников интересуется зарабатыванием очков больше, чем качеством контента, эту задачу вряд ли удастся решить.

Comment: особенно бесит когда ищешь по английски, а выходит три страницы кривых переводов и не выходит оригинальной статьи...

Comment: *Если на ваш запрос к поисковику в выдаче есть сайты с машинным переводом, но нет Stack Overflow на русском, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш вопрос в русскоязычном сообществе.* - вероятно стоит уточнить, что если есть подходящий ответ, то и его тоже нужно опубликовать. Это очевидно, но новые пользователи могут неправильно понять по смысл.

Comment: Наткнулся на ещё один автопереводной сайт - stackanswers.net У этих я даже не нашёл ссылки на оригинал.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Большое спасибо! Кстати, у меня сайт полностью на английском отображается...

Answer (score 10):

Есть небольшая проблема, которую я вижу в этом занятии.
А именно: когда персона задает вопрос, который на основном стаке уже был задан, его/её часто отправляют туда из комментариев. И на этом активность в вопросе заканчивается.
**Это не единичный случай**

Comment: ссылка в комментарии на ответ в другом месте уже может помочь. Ничто не мешает опубликовать свой ответ, особенно если вы думаете, что это бОльшему количеству людей может помочь (более ясное и/или краткое на более доступном языке). Ответы на Stack Overflow не только и не столько для автора существуют (я плюсы по ответам, которым уже больше 10 лет получаю)

Comment: Соглашусь, это проблема. [Было бы здорово писать полноценный ответ вместо комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/6). На мой взгляд, в таких случаях, можно либо явно просить автора комментария написать ответ, либо, если позволяет время, писать ответ самостоятельно. Проблема довольно интересная, хорошо бы отдельно подумать всем вместе как её решать.

Comment: Встречал другую по характеру проблему, но связную с ссылками на ответы в комментариях(на en версии SO): при схожих вопросах могут образоваться циклы из ссылок, когда после переходов возвращаешься на первый вопрос(!), с минимумом полезной информации в промежутках. Не очень весело если честно :С

Answer (score 2):

Идея переводить вопросы(особенно нишевые) с EN версии мне кажется интересной, но я не раз сталкивался с плохой реакцией сообщества на авторов которые сами отвечали на свой вопрос.

Я бы с удовольствием переводил ответы по Rails(в EN SO их много), но не заминусуют ли меня?

Comment: Зависит от выбора вопроса-ответа (далеко не все хороши, независимо от количества голосов, иногда картина в достаточной степени проясняется только из совокупности ответов и комментариев к ним, поэтому *хороший* перевод видимо должен творчески включать всю значимую информацию (а это еще перевод?)), ну, и естественно от качества перевода (литературности получившегося русского текста)

Comment: если ответа на такой вопрос нет на ru.so, q/a качественно оформлен и будет полезен в дальнейшем, то репутация вряд ли пострадает. На сайте есть заплюсованные самответы.

Comment: Плохая реакция возникает в случаях, когда авторский ответ сводится либо к *"спасибо, разобрался"*, либо к *"ошибка была совсем не тут"*. Просто выбирайте для перевода вопросы с более интересными ответами.