# Вместе на пользу сообщества: какие проблемы глобального русскоязычного ИТ-сообщества видите вы?

Tags: обсуждение

***Пожалуйста, обратите внимание!*** Этот вопрос касается всего русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков в самом широком смысле слова. Он не про наш сайт. Вопрос про индустрию в общем.

---

Невозможно научиться тому, о чем не знаешь: крайне важно какие знания доступны людям, в каком объеме. Проблема создания, накопления и поддержки знаний по программированию одна и та же во всем мире, но принимает разную форму на разных языках. Например, если посмотреть на историю запуска Stack Overflow на английском, можно заметить уникальную особенность — до того, как сайт появился на свет, в англоязычном интернете существовали две критичные проблемы того времени:

- Отсутствовала структурированная база знаний. Найти ответ на любой вопрос было очень сложно и занимало уйму времени.
- Поисковая выдача была забита ссылками на сайты, которые не показывали людям ответы, пока те не заплатят за доступ к сайту.

Страдали все без исключения. Переломный момент в жизни англоязычного сообщества произошел тогда, когда люди стали решать эти проблемы сообща: запустили Stack Overflow и начали собирать знания на сайте под лицензией CC-BY-SA.

На мой взгляд, у Stack Overflow на русском есть перспектива стать одним из ключевых источников знаний на русском языке, аналогично тому, чем стал Stack Overflow на английском в жизни англоговорящего разработчика. Чтобы достичь такого успеха, нам необходимо сообща решать актуальные проблемы всего русскоязычного сообщества. Первый шаг на этом пути — сбор проблем сообщества, которые мы видим. Затем, обсуждение и выбор тех, которые мы хотели бы решить. Далее, *решение выбранных проблем вместе на пользу сообщества*.

«Великий путь, начинается с маленького шага.» Коллеги, предлагаю начать наш путь не откладывая! Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями о проблемах сообщества, которые видите вы или ваши коллеги. Для того, чтобы отзывы можно было проанализировать, я подготовил несколько опорных вопросов. Пожалуйста, оформите ваши мысли о проблемах сообщества в виде ответов на эти вопросы.

1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищете ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?
2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?
3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?
4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?
5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?
6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Пожалуйста, присоединяйтесь к обсуждению и приглашайте заинтересованных коллег! Вместе мы гораздо больше, чем просто сумма индивидуумов.

---

Если вы хотите ответить на эти вопросы анонимно, пожалуйста, используйте [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfec1uCjPTka_ClVM-MijbKi3Bd86Vvn2fuzuMig0wTvTc0Dw/viewform). Мы обязательно учтем все анонимные отзывы в дальнейших обсуждениях.

Comment: "Поисковая выдача была забита ссылками на сайты, которые не показывали людям ответы, пока те не заплатят за доступ к сайту" о_О ни разу таких сайтов не встречал

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/15479, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/594/15479

Comment: @Suvitruf [Вот](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) один из самых назойливых представителей того времени.

Comment: @Suvitruf На мой взгляд, смежные вопросы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8722/6, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/6

Comment: @Suvitruf Мне кажется ваш комментарий со ссылками вводит всех в заблуждение. Этот вопрос про сообщество в глобальном смысле, не про наш сайт! Как думаете, может стоит удалить комментарий?

Comment: "Этот вопрос касается всего русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков в самом широком смысле слова" - тогда это разве не оффтоп?

Comment: @Suvitruf Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос?

Comment: Мета для вопросов про SO и сеть SE. Абстрактные вопросы про индустрию и т.п. - это же оффтоп. В своё время оффтопом сделали разговоры о работе, к примеру.

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, верно. Мета еще и для взаимодействия компании с сообществом.

Comment: Не хватает меток `[источник-не-указан]` и `[орисс]`.

Comment: >Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики? Нетерпеливость и нетерпимость.

Comment: 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите *(ищете)* ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? (очепятка, разрешите поправить?)

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич Спасибо, поправил! =) https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/2500/2

Comment: Я писал о 2х проблемах https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-so-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/8970#8970. По сути одна глобальная - у большинства "старичков" нет понимая что такое веб-разработка.

Answer (score 19):

> 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Часто возникает необходимость задать уточняющий вопрос автору, но это часто бывает невозможно (на сторонних ресурсах), либо автор более не активен/не доступен.

> 2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

Ответы нахожу в Google, где с недавнего времени перестал игнорировать сайты с автоматическими переводами, т.к. позволяет выполнять поиск одновременно и по русским ресурсам, и по автопереводам. Проблема возникает лишь та, что озвучена в п.1.

> 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Ну, как-бы, на поиск решения и тратиться... Зачастую бывает так, что не будучи компетентным в какой-либо сфере приходиться перефразировать поисковый запрос по нескольку раз, как раз таки из-за незнания терминов и других вещей, которые на прямую влияют на поисковую выдачу.

> 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Английский язык... Но в последнее время развитие переводчиков даёт надежду, что в недалёком будущем эта проблема может исчезнуть.

> 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Если в общем, то ничего не мешает. На примере той-же Википедии в этом можно убедиться. Если-же речь идёт о ruSO, либо какой-то другой аналогичной коммерческой платформе, то на мой взгляд мешает конфликт интересов и целей людей, которые наполняют базу знаниями и владельцами ресурса, а так-же отсутствие сплочённого сообщества.

> 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Конечно задаю, но в силу различных причин, почти никогда не получаю ответы и это одна из главных причин моего нахождения здесь.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересный ответ. Думаете, в машинном переводе будет настолько сильный скачек, что будет приятно читать подобные сайты?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky при поиске решения проблемы красота изложения материала отходит на второй план. Даже сейчас при вызове из контекстного меню Google Chrome "Перевести на русский", перевод зачастую вполне приемлемый.

Comment: `красота изложения материала отходит на второй план`

 - Ага, главное скорость

Comment: @AntonSorokin это сарказм?

Comment: @XelaNimed неа [коммент просит символов]

Answer (score 12):

> 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Отсутствие информации по многим вопросам в русско-язычном интернете. Наличие сайтов с корявыми автопереводами в поисковой выдаче. См. ответ на 2-й вопрос.

---

> 2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

Топ10 или Топ20 выдачи гугла (реже Яндекса или DuckDuckGo). У SO и ruSO конечно приоритет, но нередко приходится просмотреть все 10-20 результатов, чтобы найти нужную инфу. Главная проблема не SO-сайтов - обилие флуда, рекламы, элементов оформления и т.п. Зачастую ответ или подсказка закопана на 12-й странице темы "обо всем". По хорошему, конечно бы, мигрировать все прикладные знания в SO.

---

> 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Больше всего времени уходит на вникание в материалы и схожие проблемы со схожими решениями, сопоставление условий и результатов. Но тут никаких других вариантов, вроде бы, нет - надо вникать.

---

> 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Неумение и/или нежелание искать ответы и/или нормально формулировать свои вопросы. Но это всё никак не уникально для русскоязычных разработчиков.

---

> 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Мешает перечисленное в пункте 4. Мешает драма периодически вспыхивающая на Мете "на пустом месте", приводящая к обидам и отдалению некоторых участников.

Хорошо было бы поднять активность SO в России - нужно больше встреч, событий, митапов, хакатонов и т.п. под эгидой SO (дополнил в комментариях).

---

> 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Очень редко, т.к. нагуглить проще и результат лучше сформулирован. С коллегами обсуждаются и выясняются именно рабочие моменты и специфические элементы разработки "нашей" системы.

---

P.S. При этом я вижу очень много того, что SO сделал правильно и хорошо! Мы часто обсуждаем проблемы, и совсем редко - успехи. Хочется отметить чистоту интерфейса и четкость структурирования информации "Вопрос-Ответ". Удачную модель репутации. Самомодерацию участниками. Поддержание порядка сообществом и модераторами. И многое другое.

Comment: *Хорошо было бы поднять активность SO в России - нужно больше встреч, событий, митапов, хакатонов и т.п. под эгидой SO.* - я это понимаю как, нужно предоставить участникам общаться на *отвлеченные темы*, а не только отвечать на вопросы...

Comment: @Bald ИМХО SO можно было бы чуть больше "засвечиваться" со всякими событиями, чтобы привлечь больше специалистов. Побольше раскрывать свои core values. Общение на отвлеченные темы, это все же несколько иное.

Comment: можете раскрыть тему событий и как это поможет привлечь специалистов, как Вы это представляете?

Comment: Мне представляется, что не знай я про английский SO (в силу любых причин, например не знания англ.яз), ruSO для меня был бы сродни Тостеру или Хэшкоду или %вставьте имя площадки% и я мог бы про него узнать либо из поисковой выдачи (лучший вариант), либо по упоминаниям на других площадках, которые я посещаю. Так вот мне и кажется, что можно было бы как-то повысить частоту упоминаний ruSO, и сделать это, лучше, там где тусуются специалисты (оффлайн или онлайн).

Comment: я не верю что специалисты не знают про SO, а если знают то на основании рекламных банеров они знают о существовании ruSo, но принимать участие не особо спешат, надо решать эту проблему. IMHO конечно же

Comment: поправочка, с *большого брата* реклама видна только *[Только русскоязычным](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50009757#50009757)*

Comment: Важно не только абстрактное знание (я вот знаю про Тостер или ВопросыМейлРу или %имя_ресурса%), но и репутация и некоторый элемент вовлечения. То есть увидев где-то что-то вне поисковой выдачи, я скорее проникнусь к ресурсу доверием.

Comment: По делу написано. 4-й пункт и 5-й особенно поддерживаю, когда вижу это, хочется уйти отсюда на пару недель пока война не закончится. Терпимости к друг другу мало пока-что. Пока всё надеюсь на лучшее.

Comment: @L.F.C.: Скоро закончится, не волнуйтесь

Comment: @Bald специалистам на SO обычно не смогут помочь. У них обычно проблемы гораздо сложнее, чем задают на SO.

Comment: @AntonSorokin это понятно, но не все же участвуют в сообществе только поэтому, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! Очень интересно. Не могли бы вы раскрыть более детально «*По хорошему, конечно бы, мигрировать все прикладные знания в SO.*»? Как вы видите подобное? Контекст. Как–то мы договорились с несколькими проектами Яндекса на ведение поддержки их сообществ у нас на сайте и ребята опубликовали несколько базовых вопросов на свою тему с ответами. Вопросы заминусовали, подняли обсуждения на Мете о необходимости подобного. Подскажите, что думаете?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky думаю,что только через кристаллизацию .. т.е. заложение системы ценностей и идеи ресурса, создание насыщенного раствора людей и вопросов, воспитание умения формулировать вопросы и ответы, коллективное модерирование и прореживание, вознаграждение лучшего. Идея SO сама по себе отлична и стоит ее продолжать, исправляя мелкие проблемы, типа наплыва плохих вопросов, драм, и т.п.

Comment: @L.F.C. можете пояснить, между кем проходит война? я на сервисе полгода, постоянно о ней слышу, но никогда не нахожу противников. Можете поделиться сслыкой?

Comment: @michael_best нет смысла это мусолить. Всё есть в основном чате. Искать специально не буду, сейчас график уж слишком лихой, времени нет на SO, сорри.

Comment: @michael_best См. например профиль участника D-Side: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side

Answer (score 11):

> до того, как сайт появился на свет, в англоязычном интернете существовали две критичные проблемы того времени:
>
> - Найти ответ на любой вопрос было очень сложно и занимало уйму времени.

Нет, информация находилась легко и непринуждённо.

> - Поисковая выдача была забита ссылками на сайты, которые не показывали людям ответы, пока те не заплатят за доступ к сайту.

Такие сайты и раньше, и сейчас встречались с одинаковой частотой и никак не мешали и не мешают.

> Страдали все без исключения.

Я не страдал.

> Переломный момент в жизни англоязычного сообщества произошел ... когда ... запустили Stack Overflow

Нет.

> На мой взгляд, у Stack Overflow на русском есть перспектива стать одним из ключевых источников знаний на русском языке, аналогично тому, чем стал Stack Overflow на английском в жизни англоговорящего разработчика.

Нет. Пока не появятся на русском такие же сайты, как полторы сотни сайтов Stack Exchange.

> 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке?

Почти никаких, за исключением следующего: сложно найти свои собственные вопросы/ответы и темы с великолепными вопросами/ответами других людей, которые в своё время мне очень помогли и запомнились на других сайтах (программерских форумах), которые зачахли после появления SO.

> 2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов?

Свободно читаю по-английски поэтому мне сложно судить, есть ли *большая* проблема на русском.

Пожалуй, главная проблема такова: раньше русскоязычных программерских форумов было много, и если новичку не помогут на одном (закроют вопрос как дубликат и т. п.), то он получит ответ на втором-третьем и т. д. форуме. А сейчас таких сайтов стало намного меньше...

> 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

На отфильтровывание огромного количества неправильных, но заплюсованных ответов на StackOverflow. Никак не улучшить, время упущено.

> 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Незнание английского языка. Неумение искать информацию. Нежелание учиться. Справедливого для говорящих на любом языке.

> 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Судя по тому, что с ресурса уходят легендарные личности, мешаете лично вы, Nicolas. Никак не решить. Генеральная линия партии не позволит ничего менять.

> 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс?

Редко, но задаю. Каждый второй обижается на любую критику и воспринимает с обидой сомнение в собственных знаниях.

Comment: Со вступлением поспорю, по крайней мере на момент открытия SO лет 9 назад, он действительно стал глотком свежего воздуха среди EE и форумов. Позже ситуация несколько выровнялась, но SO безоговорочно захватил топы выдач поисковых запросов по проблемам с разработкой ПО.

Comment: @Kromster - то, что SO захватил топ это несомненно. Но и до его появления никаких проблем с поиском информации не было. Лично для меня.

Comment: По поводу поиска информации лет так 10-12 назад, я поспорю всё-таки. Русскоязычных версий ответов на свои вопросы было трудновато найти. На английском - легко, согласен, но уж точно не на русском или любом словянском. 4-й пункт поддерживаю!

Comment: `...отфильтровывание огромного количества неправильных, но заплюсованных ответов на StackOverflow...` -- весьма актуально. Вероятно в рамках существующей модели оценки (все голоса равны) проблема не решается

Comment: @L.F.C. - 10-12 лет назад интернет был моложе, информации в нем было меньше, чем сейчас, на любых языках.

Comment: "Такие сайты и раньше, и сейчас встречались с одинаковой частотой и никак не мешали и не мешают." - лет 10 назад весь топ поиска по техническим вопросам был забит experts exchange. Очень мешало. Потом его гугл забанил, поэтому сейчас и "не мешают".

Comment: Возможно у англоговорящей аудитории это "раньше" проходило иначе...

Answer (score 10):

> 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Проблем особо не испытываю, за исключением того, что ответа нет по первым 10 ссылкам в google. В большинстве случаев я тогда просто ухожу искать ответы на английском и все.

> 2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

Чаще всего это запрос через google или иду в документацию. Сложно судить, так как зачастую я просто читаю то, что есть на английском. Например по коду ошибки в гугле в топе просто чаще появляются сайты на английском. Что первое в поиске было, то и читаю. Возможно по этому каких то глобальных проблем в ру сегменте не вижу.

> 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Во первых, часто в поиске находится много однотипных простых решений задач, на подобии hello world. А сложных примеров не хватает. Во вторых, при поиске на ruSO зачастую попадаются однотипные вопросы\ответы не особо отличающиеся друг от друга, и никак не решающие мою задачу.

> 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Судя по тем, кто задает большинство вопросов на SO, новички даже не пытались гуглить и смотреть на английском(или вообще хоть что-то сами смотреть). Для львиного количества вопросов достаточно скопировать ошибку из вопроса, чтобы получить развернутый и качественный ответ на enSO. Отсюда я делаю вывод, что многие недооценивают важность знания английского.

Про опытных, не могу выделить какую-то общую проблему.

> 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Если говорить об ruSO, то складывается впечатление, что это помойка однотипных вопросов/ответов с редким появлением чего то полезного и интересного.

Например я часто слежу за веткой sql, и львиная доля вопросов там о том, как сделать join или одну из его вариаций. Информации и учебников об этом и так тонны. Я не понимаю, какую ценность несут тучи таких вопросов\ответов. То есть это не выглядит базой знаний. Такие вопросы\ответы  не добавляют новой ценности в базу знаний, и возможно провоцируют задающих снова задавать свои вопросы не обращаясь к поиску вообще.

Еще, часто информация разбросана в куче мест маленькими ответами. Из-за этого тяжело сразу составить полную картину по нужному вопросу.

Как следствие, было бы приятно иметь базу без кучи мусора и с понятной навигацией. 
Например, сейчас по меткам python + pandas я просто смотрю периодически ответы и таким образом вижу неизвестные мне ранее подходы. Я бы хотел делать так и с другими метками, но нет желания перечитывать тонны одного и тогоже.

Я уже 3 раз редактирую это место. По этому как вывод:
Проблема: В современной базе ruSO куча бесполезного мусора
Решение: Мусор надо убирать и желательно не позволять ему появляться вновь.

> 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Чаще всего нагуглить нужный ответ проще, чем задавать вопрос в оффлайне. Если я задаю такие вопросы, то обычно для получения удовольствия от беседы. По этому улучшать тут ничего и не надо.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Не могли бы как–то пояснить «помойка однотипных вопросов/ответов» и «иметь базу без кучи мусора»?

Comment: "Информации и учебников об этом и так тонны.  Возможно провоцируют задающих снова задавать свои вопросы не обращаясь к поиску вообще." Возможно, многие новички не читают книг, а предпочитают краткие гайды или урвать небольшой кусочек информации для решения конкретной задачи. Да и вообще навыки поиска у новичков могут быть плохо развиты. Если говорить про то, что вы называете мусором, то надо делать свалки. Что-то вроде места с вопросами от новичков для новичков... А иначе , мне кажется, ужесточение политики чистки может привести к конфликтам.

Comment: @AntonyRaevski прочитайте мой следующий ответ. Я пришел к схожим с вами выводам)

Comment: @Viktorov да, вчера еще прочел, но после того, как коммент оставил

Answer (score 10):

Немного моих мыслей о работе с ruSO и и опыте связанным с ним. Я решил написать отдельный вопрос, чтобы развернуть мнение в другом моем ответе в этой ветке.

**Предыстория:**
Я уже несколько лет неспешно отвечаю на вопросы на этом ресурсе, в основном отслеживая метки `sql` и `oracle`. Я прошел несколько стадий:

1. Сначала мне было интересно, я гнался за кармой и отвечал на все подряд.
2. Я стал замечать, что большинство вопросов можно было задать в гугл. Эти вопросы о том, как сделать `join`, или что это за ошибка. Чаще всего в интернете уже полно ответов на такие вопросы, надо просто потратить 5-10 минут на чтение документации или статей или вопросов на различных ресурсах(в том числе и самом ruSO)
3. Теперь я чаще всего не даю ответы на простые вопросы, мне лень. Бывает стараюсь подсказать человеку в комментариях.

**Какие из этого я делаю выводы:**
1. Ответы на простые вопросы провоцируют людей не вникать в их код. Считаю, что чаще всего это медвежья услуга.
2. Ответы и вопросы не несут ценности. Это мусор, который чаще всего мешает найти действительно нужные и сложные вещи, с которыми не разобраться за 5 минут.
3. Интересных и полезных вопросов не очень то много.

**Так чего же мне еще не хватает:**
Я признаю, что простые вопросы все равно нужны и помощь новичкам все равно имеет ценность. Вот только, это не формирует "полезную" базу знаний. Лично мне было бы интереснее отвечать на "сложные" вопросы. Это позволяет мне узнавать новое и развиваться как специалисту. И в зависимости от фаз луны я готов потратить на ответ несколько часов. А иногда мне нужна помощь в "сложных" вопросах, иногда я даже готов за это платить. Но, как мне кажется, карма - это не достаточная плата для сложных вопросов.

**Мысли о возможных решениях:**
1. Возможно было бы удобно, если бы вопросы от новичков и опытных пользователей разделялись и можно было бы по настроение выбирать в поиске простые или сложные вопросы. Или еще какой то индикатор "сложных/простых" вопросов. А может быть это должен быть отдельный ресурс. Тогда будет интересно не только отвечать, но и смотреть другие вопросы.
2. Не все и не всегда готовы тратить свое время, чтобы разобраться в действительно сложном вопросе. Было бы удобно если бы можно было устраивать конкурс с финансовым вознаграждением. Может быть это могла бы быть криптоплатформа с оплатой криптовалютой, которая начислялась бы как карма и ее можно было бы продавать. Или может это просто кнопочка "дать денег автору вопроса\ответа". В общем я сам еще не знаю =)

PS:
Мне кажется, ресурс с учетом моих хотелок был очень полезен для развития баз знаний в русском сегменте.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93041/discussion-on-answer-by-viktorov-------).

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Никаких, я не ищу ответы на русском языке.

> 2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

1) Главная проблема таких сайтов в том, что там информации драматически мало, и что найти решение на английском гораздо быстрее и что эта ситуация не изменится никогда, так как англоязычных юзеров гораздо больше, чем русскоязычных, и, как следствие, они будут лопатить контента гораздо больше, их база вопросов/ответов всегда будет больше и полнее. 
Решения я тут не вижу никакого, как и причины, зачем бы тут вообще что-то решать. Пока англоязычных юзеров больше, чем русскоязычных, их база будет больше, решение проблем у них будет найти легче, и потому все, даже русскоязычные юзеры, которые владеют английским, будут искать решение своих проблем там.

2) Ещё одна проблема таких сайтов - удержать и развивать сообщество. У меня есть опыт администрирования сообщества, и я на практике видел, что, какие бы цели сообщество не ставило, без активных участников эти цели так и остаются целями. Решение очевидно - беречь каждого активного участникак как зеницу ока, так как на 1 активного участника может быть 10 000 однодневок.

3) Третья проблема - это туманные цели сообщества. Если цель не конкретизирована, если её нельзя взвесить и измерить, то нельзя и понять, куда это сообщество движется. Решение - четкая и понятная цель и возможность увидеть, насколько сообщество к этой цели близко.

4) Четвертая проблема - отсутствие обратной связи. Если участники сообщества не могут понять, куда движется это сообщество, если непонятно, как действия участников влияют на сообщество, то возникает ощущения топтания на месте, что трактуется как просто потеря времени. Сообщества, которые никуда не движутся - умирают. Решение - показать участникам, что они важны, что на них не наплевать. Это могут быть мини-конкурсы, организация встреч, прямые линии с руководством, записи в блоге, раздача мерча (футболок, наклеек, носков, ручек, тетрадок), активные действия по запросам от участников и отчет по ним и прочие бонусы. Чтобы каждый новенький участник, зайдя на сайт, захотел бы на нем остаться и стать частью сообщества, а не просто своим участием подбивать какие-то циферки в каких-то отчетах.

5) Пятая проблема - это вера в то, что сообщество может достичь точки, когда станет саморегулируемым. Сообществу всегда нужен вожак, ему всегда нужен руководитель, ему всегда нужен человек, который способен что-то решить, что-то сделать, принять волевое решение, повести сообщество за собой. Сообществу нужен кто-то, кто будет решать возникающтие проблемы. Интернет сообщество - это не демократия, интернет сообщество - это вечеринка, куда каждый приходит со своей целью, где всегда есть хозяин вечеринки, который заказывает музыку. Ну а гость всегда может уйти, если ему музыка не понравится.

> 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

У меня нет такой проблемы, потому улучшать тут что-либо я не вижу смысла.

> 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Говоря о той категории юзеров, что задают вопросы на русскоязычной части SO, я могу выделить несколько проблем:

1) Неграмотность. Не только в правилах русского языка, но даже в техническом плане. Просто хорошо заданных вопросов драматически мало.

2) Отусутствие желания преодолевать неграмотность. Отсутствие желания даже оформить свой вопрос. Отсуствие желания банально даже в справке поглядеть информацию о том, как задавать вопросы.   Вопросы-техзадания. "Королевские" вопросы (которые заканчиваются на "жду ваших предложений", "свяжитесь со мной в личке и объясните мне", "вы ничего не понимаете, я сам лучше знаю про свой вопрос", "Срочно помогите сдать курсач", "Я сделала, а оно не работает" и т.д.)

3) незнание английского языка

> 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Я считаю, что просто база вопросов/ответов на русском языке никому не нужна. С такbм же успехом можно просто составить сайт автопереводов английского SO (которые, кстати, уже давно есть) и цель достигнута, можно закрываться. 
Что касается `свободной базы знаний`, то это понятие мне не знакомо. Спрашивая/отвечая на вопросы на сайте SO, мы пополняем базу SO, то есть база принадлежит SO и только SO имеет приоритетное право ей распоряжаться, потому про свободную базу мне не понятно.

> 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

В оффлайне я, в основном, как и в онлайне, на вопросы больше отвечаю, чем задаю. Выглядит это как обычная беседа неглупых и интеллигентных людей. Считаю, что так и должен выглядеть процесс общения, ничего улучшать тут не планирую.

Comment: Про "свободную базу", кстати, интересное замечание. Вдвойне интересно тем, что SO активно пытается блочить сайты, копирующие вопросы.

Comment: @Suvitruf откда у вас такие сведения? В футере написано *"пользовательское содержимое попадает под действие лицензии cc by-sa 3.0"*, если лицензия соблюдена - то копируй сколько влезет.

Comment: @Kromster https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/15479

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.  «Отсутствие желания» — не соглашусь. Если бы желания не было, вероятно, они бы сюда вообще не пришли. С другой стороны, соглашусь, далеко не все могут внятно сформулировать свою проблему. И это не всегда зависит от технической квалификации человека. В остальном, очень интересный взгляд на ситуацию, спасибо. Проанализирую, посмотрю, как можно сделать сайт лучше.

Comment: @Suvitruf Пожалуйста, поясните, что вы подразумеваете под «активно блочить»?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну, есть сайты с автопереводами. На них, насколько я вижу, указан источник. Формально они лицензию не нарушают. Но вы пытаетесь их выдавить из поисковой выдачи.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы совершенно не верно интерпретируете вопрос, на который ссылаетесь: мы блокируем публикацию сообщений со ссылками на эти сайты на Stack Overflow. Причем добавляем эти сайты в список по запросу самих участников. Как вы вообще представляете себе «выдавливание» другого сайта из поиска?)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вы сами предлагали жаловатсья в гугл на такие сайты.

Comment: @Suvitruf про автопереводы: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306 и https://support.google.com/webmasters/forum/AAAA2Jdx3sUthnt2ShGjDQ/?hl=en&gpf=d/category-topic/webmasters/chit-chat/thnt2ShGjDQ

Comment: @Nofate так это тут при чём? Это уже правила Гугла, а я про двойственность политики SO в отношении "свободной базы".

Comment: @Suvitruf не вижу противоречий. база свободна по CC - скачивай, кто хочет. с сайтами с автопереводами борется гугл, SO ему по помогает, потому что SO важна выдача, ничьи правила не нарушаются.

Comment: @VladD ну я просто на вопросы попробовал ответить.

Answer (score 5):

Встряну - "...Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?..." - нужна не база знаний сама по себе, а комплекс инструментов позволяющий пользоваться этой базой для ответов на практические вопросы. А это предполагает использование технологий искусственно интеллекта, решающих задачу автоматического обобщения ответов, данных экспертами SO, и автоматический синтез решения пользователя, который пришел на SO со своей проблемой. Я знаю, как решить эти проблемы, однако сомневаюсь, что на SO достаточно финансовых ресурсов, чтобы заняться этим делом (если же готовы - то дайте знать).

Поэтому нужно говорить не о базе знаний, а об интересах людей вокруг SO, а они разные. Руководству SO важен трафик, для профессионалов IT нужна взаимная помощь в решении профессиональных вопросов и мнение экспертов по смежным темам, нормальным студентам получить бесплатную консультацию, чтобы научиться, и двоечникам - халява, чтобы спихнуть лабу или курсач. Я думаю из множества названных целевых групп, единственной без которой нельзя обойтись, - это профессионалы IT. Я могу причислить себя к этой группе, хотя для меня основным занятием является разработка алгоритмов, а их реализация в виде программ - это важнейшая задача, но только после того, как будет решена первая.

Ну так вот мне нужна не база знаний (большинство вопросов я решаю с помощью ГуглоЯндекса), а общение с профессионалом, которое может существенно сузить поиск. Когда пришел на форум, здесь были VladD, Vlad from Moscow, которые куда-то пропали, после чего капитализация SO, имхо несколько снизилось. Той группе, к которой я принадлежу, ценна не столько база знаний, сколько ценны люди на SO, которые могут дать квалифицированный ответ.

Теперь по поводу русского языка - я "лицо кавказкой национальности" и очень хорошо понимаю, что владение русским языком в совершенстве - это мое огромное конкурентное преимущество. И для всех русскоязычных людей, независимо от того, где они живут, очень полезно, чтобы на русском языке в Интернет было как можно больше качественных текстов. Очевидно, что англоязычный Интернет всегда будет больше русского, но русскоязычный всегда будет больше грузинского или украинского. И размер сегмента - это не тот аргумент. Аргумент - это преимущества, которые получают русскоязычные люди, обсуждая проблемы на русском языке, и здесь нужно брать пример с японцев и китайцев, которые имеют эти преимущества, сохраняя свои национальные языки в качестве языка научного и инженерного общения (пример патенты на Японском языке).

Answer (score 4):

Проблема сообщества в том, что, к сожалению, очень много людей не умеют в английский. И, как правило, это именно те, кто задают вопросы. В тоже время, специалисты, которые могут ответить на сложные вопросы, сидят, преимущественно на en сайтах, т.к. аудитория больше, а следовательно и материалов.

> Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос
>   по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую
>   фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Я никогда не ищу вопрос на русском языке, потому что:

1. Быстрее найти на английском.
2. Качество и количество ответов будет больше.

> Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском
>   языке]? В чём вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы её
>   решили?

В русском сегменте есть только материалы по мейнстримным темам, но даже эти материалы обычно устаревшие.

> На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете?
>   Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Сравнение вариантов решения и рассмотрение альтернатив. Это зависит от личного опыта человека, тут ничего не поделать.

> Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные
>   разработчики?

1. Не хотят что-либо делать сами. Не знаю, возможно дело в образовании и этой дебильной идеей с ЕГЭ и тестами, когда люди не могут сами искать информации и обрабатывать её.
2. Не хотят учить английский.
3. Если говорить про специалистов, то, в большинстве своём, они не видят смысла отвечать на сайтах в ru сегменте.

> Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском
>   языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

1. Глупые правила. Хотя, они идут, по большей части, из en сегмента.
2. То, что ориентация тупо на бездушное хранилище знаний, где вырезается общение и дружеская атмосфера.

> Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как
>   выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

1. Иногда.
2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]/
3. 42.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Создается впечатление, что выводы в ответе основаны на ложных предположениях. Например, я вполне знаю английский, но предпочитаю задавать вопросы на Stack Overflow на русском. «Качество и количество ответов будет больше» — аналогично: покажите, пожалуйста, среднее количество ответов в одном вопросе и количество отвеченных на обоих сайтах. «Глупые правила» — пожалуйста, уточните, какие именно правила «глупые» и в чем заключается «глупость»?

Comment: "Создается впечатление, что выводы в ответе основаны на ложных предположениях. Например, я вполне знаю английский, но предпочитаю задавать вопросы на Stack Overflow на русском". Я вроде так и сказал - "большинство" не видит смысла. Ваш пример не противоречит моим словам.

Comment: "аналогично: покажите, пожалуйста, среднее количество ответов в одном вопросе и количество отвеченных на обоих сайтах" В целом, количество и качество вопрос в en очевидно лучше/больше, т.к. en-говорящих объективно больше.

Comment: "пожалуйста, уточните, какие именно правила «глупые» и в чем заключается «глупость»" - CoC, be nice, "пассивная агрессия" и т.п. Разбирать в комментариях не имеет смысла, уже много раз это обсуждали, ни к чему не пришли.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, «большинство» — это сколько? Вы лично опрашивали «большинство»? В ответе вы пишите «ответы», в комментарии «вопросы». Это разные вещи. Нормы поведения, к слову,  прекрасны!

Comment: Я извиняюсь за прямые вопросы, но прочитав ваш ответ, почему–то создается впечатление, что ответ — это негативная эмоциональная оценка, с очень грубыми допущениями. Все–таки, хотелось бы обсудить реально наблюдаемые процессы, от которых страдают наши коллеги.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а с чего вы взяли, что они страдают? о_О Проводили опрос?

Comment: Прямо сейчас провожу! Вопрос же именно об этом.

Comment: Очень смешно выкладывать картинку с английским текстом в вопрос про пользу **русскоязычного** сообщества.

Comment: @edem сложная шутка (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 4):

```
 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой
    вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую
    фрустрацию при этом?
```

Не понимание того что я хочу спросить часто помогает авто-дополнение в гугле.
Фрустрацию вызывает выдача гугла без единого схождения искомого

```
 2. Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс? Где вы сегодня
    находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы
    видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?
```

Улучшил бы авто-дополнение при поиске(увеличение вариантов и смежных тем)
На русском нахожу тут, тостер, qa.ru(да я в курсе), иногда хабр.
Проблемы не вижу.

```
 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы
    вы улучшили этот процесс?
```

На поиск 2-3 слов по которым гугл начинает выдавать примерно то что нужно.
Создать раздел "люди которые искали это "мой запрос" потом искали вот это "запрос по которому искавшие то же что и я ушли из гугла и не вернулись назад"

```
 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные
    разработчики?
```

Отсутствие в вузах современных технологий там до сих пор бейсик и делфи.
Языковой барьер.
Бедность -> отсутствие времени/денег на оп образование себя.

```
 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском
    языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?
```

Отсутствие запроса на нее.
Создал бы её (предложение иногда рождает спрос).

```
 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как
    выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?
```

Да.
-Привет у меня "вот это" подскажи как можно "такое сделать"?.
Улучшать нечего охотно отвечают на простые вопросы, сложный не задашь устно проще показать кусок кода/подобную проблему в статье.

Answer (score 4):

Тема мне интересна, поэтому сложно пройти мимо и пассивно прочитать. Поделюсь своими мыслями.

> 1. Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищете ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую
>      фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Где-то с 2010 года такая проблема стала встречаться все реже, хотя бы потому, что официальная документация большинства языков программирования стала переводиться на русский язык. Проблема из широкого сегмента перекочевала в более узкие (конкретные инструменты, фреймворки и т.п.). У многих инструментов маленький или вообще отсутвует русскоязычный сегмент, который никак не развивается. Как можно улучшить? Каждому кто нашел какое-то решение не стеснятся им поделиться, благо в 2019 году завести собственный маленький бложик вообще не проблема. Как и в решении любой большой проблеме, начни с себя и дальше все пойдет по накатанной.

> 2. Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее
>      решили?

Стек, ру-сообщества (отдельные форумы, сайты, соц.сети, оф. документация). Документация на русском не всегда актуальна. В ру-сообществах инфа появляется с опозданием. Как исправить? Опять же не стесняться при наличии возможности активно участвовать, помогать переводами и публикациями (начнет один и дальше подтянутся). Так в свое время было с ру-сообществом php-фреймворка Yii которое было создано дай-то бог десятком энтузиастов.

> 3. На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Правильная формулировка чтобы получить результат. Так как иногда приходится оставлять только ключевые слова и перебрать с десяток страниц поисковой выдачи, а иногда попав на какой-то форум, если он открытый еще и на нем шерстить поиск. Перестать создавать закрытые от индексации сообщества.

> 4. Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Умение правильно формулировать вопросы. Нежелание делиться найденными решениями публично, но попытка заработать на их продаже. Слабая активность в сообществе (не буду писать сам, подожду пока-то кто-то сделает).

> 5. Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Пассивность и отсутствие инициативности. Все предпочитают молчаливо ждать и страдать от отсутствия решения на русском. Не желание публично делиться находками (украдут, обманут, предадут).

> 6. Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

И задаю и отвечаю (в последние 4 года чаще отвечаю). Чат, курилка, подход к рабочему месту. Улучшил бы умение правильно формулировать вопросы. Выработка дисциплины, чтобы не дергали каждые 5 минут, а вопросы задавали несколько раз в день, но пачками, когда есть возможность ответить.

Answer (score 3):

1. Как правило не ищу на русском, но если говорить о том, что ищу, то проблемы
   а) формулировка правильного запроса
   б) вероятность отсутствия нужной информации в русскоязычном сегменте
2. На русском - однозначно СО, всё остальное какое-то полуживое и маргинальное с невнятным оформлением
3. Формулировка правильного запроса
4. Отсутствие фундаментальных знаний и понимания для чего эти знания программисту нужны - это общая проблема всякоязычных программистов
5. Неплохо бы дать определение термину «свободная база знаний», но если опустить этот нюанс, то мешает созданию такой базы отсутствие заинтересованности в этом тех, кто может её качественно наполнить
6. Все мои коллеги - онлайн-коллеги ) оффлайн задаю вопросы на конференциях и митапах, в неформальной обстановке редко встречаюсь с «себе подобными» ))

Answer (score 2):

**По поводу сообщества в целом**

1. На мой взгляд нет сильных русскоязычных организованных сообществ задающих "правила игры". В основном равнение на Запад. Первые шаги не за нами как итог.
2. Мало русскоязычных авторов, пишущих книги. В основном переводы.
3. Нет своих стандартов и системы оценок.
4. Туго с придумыванием переводов и новых слов в частности. Пока преобладает sposob translita.

**По поводу сайта**

Не хватает некоего подобия содержания и как следствие уйма повторяющихся вопросов.

Comment: Содержания чего? Как это могло бы выглядеть? PS: если нажать на метку, выведутся все топики с этой меткой — вот вам и содержание. Осталось привести заголовки в понятный однозначный вид и метки правильно везде расставить...

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Вопрос про всю индустрию в общем. Не только про наш сайт.

Comment: При задании вопроса выводятся уже существующие похожие вопросы, но похоже их никто не смотрит :) Плюс есть поиск - при таком количестве вопросов/ответов, он смотрится лучше, чем содержание (на сколько я понял список всех вопросов?)

Comment: @Grundy не думаю что имеется в виду "список все вопросов", скорее всего "список типовых проблем и решений"

Comment: @DaemonHK, тут скорее поможет выборка по меткам [tag:faq]

Comment: @Grundy 47 вопросов по метке `faq` это несерьёзно.

Comment: @edem, почему? вполне нормальное количество действительно часто задаваемых вопросов.

Comment: "В основном равнение на Запад" это сильно заметно , по этому ваш ответ и не получит большого одобрения, так сказать проблемма лежит в другой плоскости (социального уклада).  _"Рабство оно не в цепях, оно в голове" - Брусилов о Николае II_

Answer (score 2):

> Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные
>   разработчики?

Я думаю основная проблема заключается в отсутствии подробных примеров применения каких либо особо-сложных моментов в различных инструментах разработки, будь то язык программирования или фреймворк.

Предложение: можно было бы в СО обозначать такие примеры определённым образом, например спец.тегом.

Answer (score 1):

Как участник сообщества, хочу поделиться своими мыслями.

> Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищите ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Когда я ищу информацию, я сталкиваюсь с двумя проблемами:

#### 1. Я не знаю терминов (ключей поиска), если область знаний для меня новая

Сложность не столько в самом поиске, сколько в описании имеющейся проблемы «правильными» словами. Как раз для этого нужны термины, которых не знает приступивший к изучению человек. Это проблема не только программирования.

На мой взгляд, одно из возможных решений — не вносить стилистические правки в вопросы, написанные начинающими разработчиками. Вероятно, новички используют одни и те же слова для описания проблемы и при поиске ее решения. Сохранение стиля написания вопроса поможет найти его тем, кто, имея тот же уровень знания дисциплины, в будущем столкнется с подобной проблемой.

Другое решение — создавать обучающие [вопросы с ответом от автора](/help/self-answer), которые простым русским языком объясняют явления, вводя термины. Например «[Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/6)» — вопрос, к слову, является одним из наиболее просматриваемых на сайте.  Чем больше таких вопросов, тем легче людям погрузиться в прикладную область.

#### 2. Мешают [машинные переводы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8722/6) в результатах поиска

Кроме того, что сайты с машинным переводом, на мой взгляд, больше похожи на спам, чем на учебные материалы и их невозможно читать, я вижу проблемы долгосрочной перспективы:

- *Содержимое, которое никто не поддерживает* быстро приходит в негодность, подобно [обветшавшему дому](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lSA6.jpg). Если мы будем просто пассивно наблюдать, то скоро нам всем придется жить на этой информационной свалке.
- *Некому задать свой вопрос*. Авторы вопросов не имеют никакого представления, что кто–то где–то увидев их вопрос на языке, которого они не понимают, задал вопрос, думая, что автор им ответит. Любой новый вопрос на таких сайтах, если бы это было возможно — это крик в пустоту.
- *Нет места тем, кто создает*, то есть всем нам. Все «задано», «отвечено», «проголосовано» и т.д алгоритмами в очень большом количестве. В таком мире мы, специалисты, желающие делиться своими знаниями, не в цене. Как и наши знания. :’(
- *Отсутствует культура как таковая.* Культура — это то, как мы взаимодействуем друг с другом. База знаний — результат культуры. Без реальных людей, нет культуры, нет базы знаний сообщества. Только тонна сгенерированных текстов.

Я чувствую опустошенность и разочарование, если представляю реальность, в которой есть лишь одно сообщество разработчиков — англоязычное, лишь одна база знаний — на английском языке, созданная лишь для тех людей, кто родился в англоязычном мире. Я верю, что мы можем создать первоклассное сообщество и базу знаний на русском языке, а не учиться по переработанным алгоритмом результатом деятельности англоязычного сообщества. Наши знания уникальны, они очень нужны окружающим нас людям. Реальные люди очень хотя видеть наши ответы на их вопросы.

**Как каждый из нас может помочь исправить ситуацию?**

1. [Пишите в поддержку поисковиков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8722/6) о [нарушении их лицензии](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306), каждый раз, когда натыкаетесь на сайт с машинным переводом.
2. Приглашайте коллег задавать вопросы и отвечать на них на [сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), участвовать в обсуждениях на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) и [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Наши коллеги не научатся задавать свои вопросы грамотно, до тех пор, пока не начнут это делать. Также как и отвечать. Это правда очень важно! Без ваших коллег мы не сможем создать по настоящему всеобъемлющую базу знаний, доступную всем и дружное сообщество.

> Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

В основном это Stack Overflow на русском и на английском, Википедия, иногда Хабр. Так же у меня есть несколько любимых сайтов по каждой теме, которую я изучаю. Ищу с фильтром по этим сайтам (например, для основ математики я использую http://mathprofi.ru).

- Stack Overflow на английском — отличный источник знаний.
- На Stack Overflow на русском, к сожалению, не так много вопросов, как хотелось бы. Решение: писать новые вопросы и ответы, призывать коллег делать тоже самое!
- На Википедии есть очень много всего интересного. Основная моя проблема — технические статьи написаны сухим языком, их сложно понять.

> Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Не хотят (не видят смысла) участвовать в интернет сообществах. На мой взгляд, причина — страх быть обруганным, униженными, высмеянным за свой вопрос, орфографическую ошибку или даже интернет–псевдоним. Довольно часто вижу подобное в Рунете. Очень здорово, что [на Stack Overflow на русском подобного никогда не было, нет и не будет](/help/key-values).

> Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Главная проблема, на мой взгляд — проявление агрессии, с одной стороны и страх, с другой.

Решением может быть (а) создание [включающей](/conduct) атмосферы знаний на сайте, (б) активное вовлечение коллег в сообщество. Второе не менее важно, чем первое: многие из нас имеют негативный опыт, который никому не хочется повторять. Важно, чтобы люди поверили и сделали еще одну попытку. Создать базу знаний сообщества можно только работая всем вместе.

> Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Не задаю. Потому что задаю их на Stack Overflow на русском. Для меня это эффективнее, а также полезнее для всех русскоязычных разработчиков.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищете ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

От случая к случаю, но в основном формулировка "запроса".
По поводу улучшение, думаю всё зависит от того, кто ищет, следовательно улучшать нужно только себя.

> Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

На различных форумах, статьях, уроках, т.е. в интернете.
Проблему.. Хм.. Не всегда конечно, но в большинстве случаев - это качество материала (сюда же отнесу и время публикации), а по поводу улучшение, тоже самое что сказано выше - улучшать себя.

> На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Как и у **[@XelaNimed](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9001/221218)** - в поисках и перефразирование "запроса".

> Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Затрудняюсь ответить на этот вопрос.

> Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Люди, те которые ищут информацию. 
Взять, например, ruSO, мало кто ищет вариант решения своей проблемы, все хотят задать вопрос, не пытаясь узнать есть ли решение его проблемы..
Думаю они считают что их вопрос уникален, а он может быть решён "100 лет назад", на том же ruSO.
Мне кажется это неисправимо :)

> Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Оффлайн нет, онлайн - да.
Это когда не могу сформулировать нормально вопрос для ruSO, задаю знакомым.
Улучшил бы себя.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие проблемы лично вы испытываете, когда ищете ответ на свой вопрос по программированию на русском языке? Что вызывает наибольшую фрустрацию при этом? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?
>      Где вы сегодня находите решения по программированию [на русском языке]? В чем вы видите главную проблему этих сайтов? Как бы вы ее решили?

Я не ищу ответы на русском т.к. я знаю английский.

> На что тратится больше всего времени при поиске решения в интернете? Как бы вы улучшили этот процесс?

Мусор типа qaru и прочих сайтов с русским контентом.

> Какую общую проблему, на ваш взгляд, испытывают многие русскоязычные разработчики?

Они не знают английский.

> Что на ваш взгляд, мешает созданию свободной базы знаний на русском языке? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

Вики - это единственный нормальный формат базы знаний.
Проблема в том, что нужны люди которые будут наполнять эту базу знаний, улучшать чужие статьи, и актуализировать старые статьи.

> Задаете ли вы вопросы по программированию коллегам в оффлайне? Как выглядит этот процесс? Что бы вы в нем улучшили?

Не задаю.

Comment: Лично был свиделем, как ты задавал вопросы докладчику :) Можно даже видео-пруф найти при желании.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это точно был коллега?   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: С `вики` совершенно согласен (так, и что  из этого следует по отношению к SO?)

Comment: @avp следует что SO это локальный максимум, тупиковая ветвь развития.

Comment: @Abyx в плане самоуправления или как "базы знаний"?

Comment: "Я не ищу ответы на русском т.к. я знаю английский."- вопрос, а что Вы вообще делаете на русскоязычном сайте ?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, я отвечаю на вопросы.