# Давайте составим четкий список решения проблемы конкурсов или что с ними делать, а потом проголосуем!

Tags: обсуждение

Пожалуйста добавьте в виде ответа свое мнение, что следует делать с вопросами конкурсами и допустимы ли они. Через (например) неделю устроим голосование по этим вараинтам. Отдельное голосование, потому что ответы скорее всего попадут в разное время.

Comment: С конкурсами никаких проблем нет и никогда не было. Все проблемы только с псевдоконкурсами, не имеющими чётких условий задачи.

Comment: @andreymal Вот и напишите ответ, там поясните такие понятия как "псевдоконкрус" и что с ними делать ;)

Comment: Не надо выносить одно и то же на голосование по нескольку раз, пока не наголосуют правильно. Приведите весомые аргументы против предыдущих решений.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я наконец-то придумал, как сделать голосование (а те спор и обсуждение) и при этом не ограничит людей в возможности добавить свой варианты. А чем вы говорите?

Comment: @HamSter Я хоть и не фронтендщик, но это-то понимаю. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Я говорю о том, что в предыдущем вопросе уже было предложено решение (проводить неформатные конкурсы на мете), и оно получило большинство голосов. Если нет веских аргументов против, может, стоит просто согласиться с этим решением? Зачем плодить уже третий вопрос об одном и том же?

Comment: То было "давайте обсудим", это "давайте подготовиться к голосованию". А про метy— вообще бред какой-то, вот к ней это отношение не имеет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, киньте, пожалуйста, ссылочку на то предложение о проведении неформальных конкурсов на мете, которое получило большинство голосов. Как-то это большинство мимо меня прошло

Comment: @avp https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10374/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я думаю, его плюсовали по разным мотивам. Я уж точно не за предложение писать конкурсы на Мете. Поэтому с большинством (imho) вы погорячились

Comment: Благодаря очередному SVG самоответу на мете появился срач из 10-ти вопросов. Надо подождать пока болезнь SVG не пройдёт сама, или пока не разрастётся до таких масштабов что станет более заметной.

Comment: ну ещё как минимум один вопрос точно будет. но надеюсь, что он будет последним.

Answer (score 4):

## Пролог

Stack Overflow это база знаний.
Это всем известный и каждому понятный факт.

Я понимаю участников, которые радеют за чистоту этой базы знаний.
Я очень остро ощущаю нехватку времени и прекрасно понимаю раздражение многих участников.
Я тоже человек и безусловно очень часто и сам его испытываю.
На данный момент я являюсь предпринимателем и до этого я долгое время занимал руководящие должности, поэтому я прекрасно понимаю, как дорого и драгоценно может быть время и как это может выводить из себя, в те моменты, когда его у тебя отнимают.

Но при этом я всегда стараюсь верить в лучшее и подразумеваю благие намерения участников.
Я не разбрасываюсь минусами и тревогами направо и налево.
Я делаю это только если вижу явное злоупотребление со стороны участников.
В первую очередь же я стараюсь объяснить в комментариях куда они попали, что здесь происходит, что от них ожидает сообщество и почему.
И меня частенько благодарят за это в ответ и исправляют вопросы.
Большинство новых пользователей просто растеряны и не понимают, что они должны здесь делать и как им здесь себя вести.
Удивительно как много может изменить простая доброжелательность.

А вот людей, которые чересчур рьяно бегут исполнять свои обязанности, обрушивая на всех подряд без исключения свой праведный гнев я уже не понимаю.
На ум мне невольно приходят ассоциации с третьим рейхом, который боролся за чистоту нации.
И мне бывает неприятно осознавать мое нахождение рядом с ними и не хочется вступать с ними в дискуссии.

Читателю может показаться, что все вышеописанное никак не относится к теме вопроса. Но я возражу: все что здесь написано имеет непосредственное отношение, к тому что мы обсуждаем.

Мне кажется что важно соответствовать не только слову, но и духу закона, как бы пафосно это не звучало.

В контексте нашего сообщества, это значит, что важнее не столько знать правила, сколько понимать почему они такие и зачем их писали. Это помогает принимать решения в сложных и неоднозначных вопросах.

В конце этого пролога мне хочется еще сказать, что понятие "*база знаний*" прекрасно иллюстрирует то, чем StackOverflow является снаружи и то, чем он является для сторонних наблюдателей.
Однако, как мне кажется, те кто постоянно апеллируют к этому утверждению допускают одну небольшую ошибку и теряют из виду, то что является сутью StackOverflow.
А сутью StackOverflow является сообщество.
StackOverflow - это мы с вами!
Если бы не было нас и если не было бы сообщества, то и этой базы знаний не существовало.

## Возвращаясь к теме

- **Я считаю, что конкурсы являются полезными как для сообщества, так и для базы знаний.**

  Конкурсы повышают активность пользователей и вовлеченность в жизнь
  сообщества. Авторы ответов прикладывают немалые усилия для участия в
  этих конкурсах, а отдельные участники вкладывают в них практически
  все накопленные знания и опыт. И отдельные ответы могут не уступать
  уже ставшими легендарными топиками по более "серьезным" темам. Их
  можно с интересом изучать и открывать для себя что-то новое.
- **Я не считаю, что конкурсы могут оказать какое-либо существенное негативное влияние на качество вопросов.**
- **Я не согласен с теми, кто считает что конкурсы подают дурной пример и массово развращают умы молодых (и не только) участников.**

  Безусловно единичные прецеденты имеют место быть, но чтобы конкурсы
  проводимые раз в году всерьез на что-то влияли я не верю и не вижу
  тому абсолютно никаких подтверждений. И почему-то я не вижу
  сторонников этой точки зрения в топе очередей проверок. Это
  исключительно умозрительные заключения, не подтверждающиеся никакой
  статистикой.
- **Также я считаю, что последовательное давление на авторов конкурса оказывает очень сильное негативное влияние на все сообщество.** И это
  (в отличии от вышеупомянутых заключений) имеет более чем реальные
  негативные последствия прямо сейчас. Мне больно наблюдать за тем, как
  черезчур активная позиция небольшого количества одних участников
  отворачивает от сообщества огромное количество других пользователей.
  И мне не хочется наблюдать за тем как будет зреть очередной раскол в
  сообществе.

Столь длинный пролог нужен был, чтобы читающие понимали, что все происходящее задевает не только участвующих в дискуссиях, но и пользователей, которые не так уж и часто высказываются, при этом являются частью сообщества, которое очень любят.
И это отражается на всем сообществе и очень многим, происходящее неприятно и доставляет боль.

Все это не добавляет популярности StackOverflow.
Мне очень не хочется наблюдать за тем как участники собачатся друг с другом.
Я очень надеюсь на благоразумие и на то, что мы найдём таки общий язык друг с другом.

**По-моему нужно поставить точку в данном вопросе и узаконить проводимые конкурсы.**
Правила конкурсов будут отдельным вопросом и во время их обсуждения также поломается много копий.
Но это уже совсем другая история и обсуждать их стоит только после того как мы решим, что данная активность является легальной.

## Я за проведение конкурсов!

Comment: "вкладывают в них практически все накопленные знания и опыт" - не вкладывают, а выбрасывают, потому что такие конкурсы являются бессвязной и плохо индексируемой поисковиками свалкой разношёрстных примеров. Конкурсы без чётких условий **вредны** для базы знаний.

Comment: @andreymal, вы являетесь специалистом в области поискового продвижения? Некоторые отвечающие подробно описывают свои действия, объясняют что они делают, зачем и почему чтобы можно было понять и повторить самостоятельно, так как если бы они отвечали на обычный вопрос. И по ключевым словам из этих ответов и объяснений и приложенному коду можно очень даже легко попасть на эти ответы из поисковой выдачи и далеко не по запросу "Новогодний конкурс 2020 stack overflow".

Comment: @andreymal, условия конкурсов и их правила это по-моему отдельный разговор. Этот вопрос лучше решать последовательно. 1. Мы голосуем за возможность проведения конкурсов. 2. Мы обсуждаем и утверждаем правила и условия конкурсов. 3. Вносим соответствующие изменения в справочную информацию.

Comment: во-первых, этих некоторых - меньшиство. Во-вторых, для ищущего будет НАМНОГО лучше, если ищущий попадёт в конкретный вопрос-ответ с несколькими вариантами решения **конкретного** вопроса вместо конкурса-свалки даже с объяснениями (другими словами, слишком общие конкурсы даже с объяснениями **противоречат** идее базы знаний в формате **вопрос-ответ** - почувствуйте разницу с форматом "невопрос-свалка примеров"). В-третьих, против самого факта существования конкурсов никто никогда не выступал, поэтому пункт 1 неактуален и никогда не был актуален

Comment: "Четкие" условия для разных условий могут быть разными. Можно решать очень строгую и четкую задачу на любом стеке технологий, можно решать задачу на строго определённом стеке технологий при этом допускать вольности при реализации. Если совсем всё по рукам и ногам связывать, то это будет не конкурс а обычный вопрос. И на него будет обычный ответ... один или два. Конкурс же подразумевает некую вариативность, а для нее нужна хоть какая-то но свобода.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, подобные вопросы/конкурсы полностью допустимы текущими правилами сайта и с ними никаких проблем нет. Напротив, те псевдоконкурсы, против которых выступаю я (а вы вообще в курсе, о каких псевдоконкурсах речь, кстати?), не имеют вообще ничего чёткого (ни задачи, ни стека, ни чего-то ещё) и не приносят ничего кроме свалковреда.

Comment: @andreymal, я искренне рад что Вы считаете что пункт 1 неактуален. (Это не сарказм)

Comment: @andreymal, я понимаю вас и согласен что у конкурсов должны быть условия и правила, но также я понимаю и организаторов конкурса и понимаю, что для конкурса также важна какая-то свобода, в противном случае его не получится. Нужно найти какой-то компромисс, который бы устроил всех.

Comment: И вместо того, чтобы искать компромисс и разбираться, где проходит граница между «нормальными» и «слишном общими» конкурсами, сообщество зачем-то начало рассуждать о существовании конкурсов в принципе. Такое чувство, что полгода моего нытья неправильно поняли абсолютно все.

Comment: @andreymal, Вы можете оставить свой ответ под этим вопросом и постараться разрешить недопонимание, после чего пригласить всех к обсуждению непосредственно правил и условий конкурсов. И уже в рамках другого вопроса пусть все выскажутся об их видении условий проведения конкурса.

Comment: Михаил, благодарю вас за такой развернутый ответ. Я полностью с вами согласен. Вы написали правду. Написали именно так, как оно и есть на самом деле. И если вчитаться внимательно в написанное вами, то как мне кажется, невозможно с вами не согласиться. Успехов вам!

Comment: @МихаилРебров составил https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11151

Comment: @МихаилРебров Я потрясен и восхищен одновременно, Вашим талантом легко  и просто объяснять сложные вещи. Слова льются легко и свободно, как рифмы Пушкина. Прочитал с большим удовольствием Ваш ответ и в большей степени не потому что Вы поддерживаете идею творческих конкурсов, хотя это и здорово, а скорее из-за глубокого проникновения в некоторые обсуждаемые проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Допустимы, не закрывать. Свое отношение выражать обычным плюсованием-минусованием.

Comment: Как именно должна быть сформулирована «допустимость» в правилах сайта?

Comment: Можно задавать такие вопросы и писать на них ответы, не опасаясь закрытия, удаления и т.п. деструктивных действий. Или вы имели в виду текст "правил сайта"? Если так, то просто не надо в этом тексте акцентировать внимание на типе вопросов. Вообще любых. Написать, что тут задают вопросы на тему IT. Все

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете стереть примерно 98% текста текущих правил?

Comment: От этого будет только польза (по крайней мере их хоть читать будут)

Comment: Очень мудрый ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

А давайте я выверну соседний ответ для контраста :)

---

## Пролог

Stack Overflow это база знаний.
Это всем известный и каждому понятный факт.

Я не понимаю участников, которые не радеют за чистоту этой базы знаний.
Пусть [идея Stack Overflow и не работает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8636), но это не является уважительной причиной опускать руки и превращать базу знаний в бессвязный форум-болталку по интересам.

Хоть я и пытаюсь верить в лучшее и подразумевать благие намерения участников, *некоторые* участники упорно отказываются вникать в суть в базы знаний или хотя бы корректно интерпретировать имеющиеся правила сайта, что по сути можно считать «явным злоупотреблением».
И в такой ситуации не остаётся ничего, кроме как разбрасываться минусами и тревогами направо и налево, ну и поднимать тему на Мете.
Я уже пытался объяснять организатором псевдоконкурсов в комментариях, куда они попали, что здесь происходит, в чём смысл формата Stack Overflow, — но был благополучно проигнорирован всеми.
И хотя они, по-видимому, не понимают формат сайта, они вовсе не растеряны и считают, что знают, что они должны здесь делать и как им здесь себя вести, хотя это на самом деле не так.
Поэтому с такими участниками **доброжелательность не работает.** (Типичная ситуация для русскоязычных форумов.)

А вот людей, которые считают, что кто-то чересчур рьяно бежит исполнять свои обязанности, обрушивая на всех подряд без исключения свой праведный гнев, я не понимаю.
Мне от этого просто становится грустно. Такие люди просто не разобрались в ситуации.

Если говорить конкретно обо мне, самого начала я имею претензии лишь к 4 (прописью: **четырём**) псевдоконкурсам, не имеющим чётких условий, авторами которых являются лишь 2 (прописью: **два**) участника. Это очень сильно далеко от «всех подряд», не так ли?

Я ничего не имею против *нормальных* конкурсов и «исполняю свои обязанности» ровно в той мере, в какой это соответствует текущим правилам сайта.

---

Мне тоже кажется, что важно соответствовать не только слову, но и духу закона, как бы пафосно это ни звучало.

В контексте нашего сообщества, это значит, что важнее не столько знать правила, сколько понимать, почему они такие и зачем их писали. Это помогает принимать решения в сложных и неоднозначных вопросах.

К сожалению, *некоторые* участники сообщества этого не понимают, что и вылилось в происходящую здесь драму.

В конце этого пролога мне хочется еще сказать, что понятие «*база знаний*» прекрасно иллюстрирует то, чем StackOverflow является снаружи и то, чем он является для сторонних наблюдателей.
Однако, как мне кажется, те, кто постоянно апеллируют к аппеляциям этого утверждения, допускают одну небольшую ошибку, искажая то, что является сутью StackOverflow.
А сутью StackOverflow является **составление базы знаний в формате вопрос-ответ**.
Конечно же, без сообщества не было бы этой базы знаний, но посмотрите вокруг — в интернете есть **тысячи форумов** на айтишную тематику, в том числе с весьма крупными сообществами!
Так что же, разве сутью StackOverflow является сообщество? Конечно же нет, сообществ в интернете и так навалом, StackOverflow тут не уникален.

Вся прелесть же в том, что **StackOverflow имеет уникальный формат, и его нужно соблюдать**. Он даже ещё более уникален, чем другие сайты формата вопрос-ответ (ответы мйэлру, хабр qa, тот же старый хэшкод и т.п.) благодаря **строгости своих правил**. Без формата он превратится в самый обычный форум, коих тысячи. Именно поэтому я «чересчур рьяно» поднимаю эту драму — я очень хочу сохранить этот уникальный формат.

## Возвращаясь к теме

- Про обычные, нормальные конкурсы с чёткими условиями задачи и внятными критериями победы я ничего не считаю. (Я их не очень люблю, но не более того.)
- **Я считаю, что псевдоконкурсы без чётких условий являются вредными для базы знаний.**

  Конкурсы (любые) повышают активность пользователей и вовлеченность в жизнь
  сообщества. Авторы ответов прикладывают немалые усилия для участия в
  этих конкурсах, а отдельные участники вкладывают в них практически
  все накопленные знания и опыт. И отдельные ответы могут не уступать
  уже ставшими легендарными топиками по более "серьезным" темам.

  Но мы же ещё помним, что сутью StackOverflow является **вовсе не сообщество**? Поэтому это всё не имеет такого большого значения.

  Конкурсы без чётких условий, может, и можно с интересом изучать и открывать для себя что-то новое (и то только если код имеет пояснения), но это всё равно не соответствует идее сайта — StackOverflow задумывался работать не так.
- **Я считаю, что псевдоконкурсы без чётких условий оказывают негативное влияние на качество вопросов.**

  Существенное или нет — сложный вопрос, однако наблюдается очевидный факт — вместо отдельных **конкретных** вопросов, которые могли бы очень хорошо индексироваться и в которые сообщество могло бы внести свой вклад (наподобие «Как раскрасить текст анимированным градиентом?» или «Как сделать анимацию волны на тексте с помощью изменения размера букв?») мы получаем свалку из **абсолютно разных** примеров, объёдинённых **абсолютно абстрактной** формулировкой («Как анимировать слово?»).

  При этом сообщество на самом деле **лишается возможности внести свой вклад** — вот, к примеру, кто-то захочет реализовать волну другим способом, отличным от имеющегося ответа. Если он напишет новый ответ под тем же псевдоконкуром — он просто потеряется в массе других ответов! Человек, ищущий, как сделать волну, просто не найдёт новый ответ, потому что до него скроллить примерно вечность, продираясь сквозь другие ответы с совершенно другими анимациями. При этом база знаний лишилась **хорошего, конкретного и индексируемого** вопроса про создание анимации волны, в котором ищущий мог бы легко изучить все интересующие его варианты. **Поэтому псевдоконкурсы вредны.**
- **Я и есть тот, кто считает что подобные псевдоконкурсы подают дурной пример и массово развращают умы молодых (и не только) участников.** :)

  Может, пока что и не массово, но я потому и поднимаю драму, чтобы до массовости дело не успело дойти.

  Раз в году, может, и не страшно, и после темы [«Новогодий конкурс узаконен»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9961) я некоторое время помалкивал (хотя уже тогда не все оказались довольны произошедшим), но когда псевдоконкурсы стали проводиться **чаще чем раз в году**, я решил, что хватит это терпеть. Не нужно доводить бардак до массовости — нужно пресечь бардак, пока не стало слишком поздно.
- **Последовательное игнорирование авторами псевдоконкурсов правил и формата сайта оказывает очень сильное негативное влияние и на базу знаний, и на сообщество.** Хотя если бы они просто соблюдали формат — никаких проблем с сообществом не было бы. Давайте не путать причину и следствие: причина — систематическое и упорное нарушение правил отдельными участниками, а негативное влияние на сообщество — это лишь следствие их деятельности. Конечно, моя «рьяность» сильно этому поспособствовала, но если бы факта нарушения правил не было бы или если бы нарушения были опервативно исправлены, то я бы в принципе не стал поднимать эту тему настолько громко, так что, опять же, моя «рьяность» это всего лишь следствие.

И их упорство отражается на всем сообществе и очень многим, происходящее неприятно и доставляет боль.

Все это не добавляет популярности StackOverflow.
Мне очень не хочется наблюдать за тем, как базу знаний, и без того не шибко качественную, **осознанно катят на дно** её участники.
Однако увы, моя надежда на благоразумие кончилась ещё полгода назад. Общего языка найти так и не получилось — ни с авторами псевдоконкурсов, ни с теми, кто постоянно жмёт в «Оставить открытым» в очереди проверок.

**Нормальные конкурсы всегда были законны. Псевдоконкурсы без чётких условий незаконны прямо сейчас.**

Правила конкурсов — это лишняя сущность; нормальные конкурсы и так неплохо вписываются в уже существующие правила написания вопросов.

## Я за проведение конкурсов!

## Я против проведения псевдоконкурсов!

---

Касательно вопроса «что делать» — закрыть да и всё, исправлять уже поздно. В крайнем случае — повесить историческую блокировку, будущим поколениям на заметку. А все новые конкурсы делать соответствующими правилам сайта.

Уже есть пример **конкретного и соответствующего правилам** конкурса [«Как создать анимированную иконку Stackoverflow»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085360) за авторством Alexandr_TT (иронично, что он при этом одновременно является «виновником торжества» со всеми этими псевдоконкурсами). Реальная полезность этого конкурса — вопрос спорный (вряд ли кто-то будет искать конкретно такую анимацию конкретно такой иконки), однако он соответствует формальным правилам: есть чётко поставленная задача, есть чётко ограниченный набор технологий — вопрос достаточно конкретный и на него можно дать объективно верный ответ. В таком конкурсе нельзя написать «абсолютно любую» анимацию, поэтому он не превращается в свалку и не вредит остальной базе знаний, и я к этому конкурсу не имею никаких претензий (можно подискутировать о «полезности», но не более того). **Никакие новые правила изобретать не требуется.**

Comment: Если кто-то захочет поставить минус (а кто-то обязательно захочет) — напишите, пожалуйста, свои возражения **по сути**, что конкретно здесь сказано неправильно и почему я не прав. И нет, утверждения вида «сообщество хочет чтобы было весело, не отнимай у нас веселье, плак-плак» хорошими возражениями не являются.

Comment: Я польщён) но прокомментирую скорее всего только вечером уже

Comment: Ну вот, минус есть, а возражений нет. Ну что за люди... Движимы эмоциями, а не разумом — не иначе.

Comment: Ну вот, три минуса есть, а возражений нет. Приходится скрипя зубами признавать, что я прав, да?

Comment: Не думаю, что ты прав. Конкурсы — это творчество. База знаний не только не замусоряется, но и наполняется шедеврами. И эти шедевры ничуть не мешают искать здесь ответ на свой конкретный вопрос. Проблема тех "тысяч форумов" не в отсуствии" жестких правил на вопросы, а в присутсвии бесцельных обсуждений типа "А: Дядя билли — кретин. В: Сам ты критин, он гений. " и 1024 страниц флуда. Жесткому формату конкурсы не мешают. И даже как часть базы знаний они хороши — человек может учиться анимировать икони, чего ему не поучиться у @Alexandr_TT например?

Comment: Андрей, по вашей просьбе, проявляя к вам уважение, комментирую, за что я поставил минус. Никогда не любил пародии на оригинал. Надеялся, что хотя бы в этот раз будет что-то новое от вас. Но нет. Более того, получилось даже как-то глупо, нелепо и местами комично. И еще добавлю отдельно: вспомните, пожалуйста, ваши злобные комментарии к конкурсу, к которому теперь, почему-то вдруг, у вас претензий нет. Я это хорошо помню. А вы? Считаю ваше мнение неустойчивым, поэтому ему не доверяю от слова совсем.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor перечитайте мой ответ ещё раз — я конкретно описал механизм, который мешает искать ответы в псевдоконкурсах, на примере анимирования слова. Жесткому формату конкурсы мешают именно по этой причине. Если я что-то описал неправильно — раскажите по пунктам конкретно, что и почему. А пока что у вас не аргументированное возражение, а просто эмоциональный отклик.

Comment: Перечитал — и где? ;)

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну то есть **по сути** у вас нечего возразить и моя «пародия» абсолютно верна и не содержит никаких неправильных выводов, да?

Comment: @andreymal `вместо отдельных конкретных вопросов, которые могли бы очень хорошо индексироваться` — Этих отдельных вопросов — прорва. Они никуда не денутся. А это "если бы да ка бы" что кто написал бы ­— не аргумент. Про умственные способности спасибо большое, вы дали мне повод привлечь сюда еще и модераторов. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor так в том-то и проблема, что эти вопросы **исчезли в свалках псевдоконкурсов**. Авторы вопросов могли бы составить конкретные условия, а авторы таких ответов могли бы на худой конец написать самоответ, сформулировав конкретный и легко гуглящийся вопрос, но вместо этого **они поддержали свалку и лишили базу знаний хороших вопросов**. Это — массовое вредительство в базе знаний по предварительному сговору.

Comment: Что значит исчезли? Куда? С сайта? Нет. Из гугла? Тоже нет. От куда?

Comment: Каких свалках? три случайных вопроса + новогодние ­— да прям свалка.

Comment: @andreymal, могу себе представить, если пустить всю вашу мощь и стремление в правильное русло, во благо сообщества, то мы вместе с вами достигнем все пределы мечтаний которые только могут быть. А пока что увы, получается только холевар. Может быть когда-нибудь что-то да поменяется. Мне бы этого очень хотелось. Будем надеяться на лучшее.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor перечитайте мой ответ ещё раз с фразы «однако наблюдается очевидный факт» и дальше по тексту — я там вполне чётко и на конкретном примере анимации слова описал, что, куда и почему исчезает.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну то есть возражений по делу никаких. Я буду ссылаться к вашим комментариям как на подтверждение правоты моей позиции, раз вы не смогли ничего конструктивно возразить.

Comment: `При этом сообщество на самом деле лишается возможности внести свой вклад — вот, к примеру, кто-то захочет реализовать волну другим способом, отличным от имеющегося ответа. Если он напишет новый ответ под тем же псевдоконкуром — он просто потеряется в массе других ответов! Человек, ищущий, как сделать волну, просто не найдёт новый ответ, потому что до него скроллить примерно вечность, продираясь сквозь другие ответы с совершенно другими анимациями. При этом база знаний лишилась хорошего, конкретного и индексируемого вопроса про создание анимации волны, ...`

Comment: `...в котором ищущий мог бы легко изучить все интересующие его варианты. Поэтому псевдоконкурсы вредны.` —   Никто не помешает задать  новый (само) вопрос с ответом. Если бы не было такого конкурса, никаких волн ни тех, ни других в базе не было бы вообще.

Comment: @andreymal, спасение утопающего дело рук самого утопающего. Успехов!

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну так почему авторы ответов до сих пор не создали-то? Другие люди создавать теперь точно не станут, потому что получится дубликат, ведь всё уже написано в конкурсе-свалке (да и копипастить чужие ответы некрасиво). В сумме выходит вред для базы знаний.

Comment: Нет, не дупликат. Захотят — будут. Не захотят — а конкурс тут причем? Виноватых искать да стрелки переводит... Эх...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor конкурс тут при том, что он провоцирует людей писать свои крутые примеры в свалку вместо того, чтобы составить крутые вопросы-самоответы — а значит несёт вред. И даже, допустим, если другие пользователи захотят создать вопрос по мотивам какого-то ответа из конкурса, то изначальный ответ ведь всё равно останется в конкурсе-свалке, и его придётся или копипастить (а это некрасиво и дубликат), или просто оставлять там же в конкурсе-свалке (а это нарушение структуры базы знаний и вред). Единственное верное решение —чтобы сами авторы ответов написали отдельные вопросы с самоответами

Comment: @VictorVosMottor не ну если модераторы дадут мне разрешение на «разборку» свалки на отдельные вопросы-ответы, то я могу и покопипастить, но мне это не кажется верным решением и вероятно вызовет недовольство авторов оригинальных ответов. Так что в сумме всё равно вред.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor и кстати обратите внимание, что в том же несчастном конкурсе анимирования слова многие ответы не имеют человеческого описания, что же за анимация там вообще сделана, а значит, отвечая на ваш комментарий «исчезли? ... Из гугла?» — **ДА, эти примеры совершенно не гуглятся по причине отсутствия описания**. Хотя это уже не имеет прямого отношения к проблеме псевдоконкурсов, этот занимательный факт всё-таки имеет место быть — у участников нет никакой мотивации писать человеческие описания к своим ответам. В нормально составленных вопросах такой проблемы не возникло бы.

Comment: @Sevastopol' и кстати насчёт «ваши злобные комментарии к конкурсу» — я сейчас попросил модераторов глянуть удалённые комментарии к этому конкурсу, и мне ответили, что там нет **ни одного моего комментария** — и это неудивительно, я тоже не помню, чтобы я там писал хоть что-то. Получается, что **вы нагло лжёте** — и я бы вам крайне не рекомендовал использовать **клевету** как инструмент доказывания своей правоты, ибо это рискует обернуться против вас.

Comment: @andreymal, а вы хорошо постарайтесь вспомнить, где вы комментировали этот конкурс и где был это спор. Поднимите, пожалуйста, всю свою историю комментирования за тот период, и тогда не будете задавать вопросы.

Comment: @Sevastopol' я прекрасно помню, как я отзывался **нейтрально** об этом конкурсе. Не знаю, что вы там себе навыдумывали.

Comment: Очень редко у меня случается так, что я практически полностью согласен с аргументами, однако абсолютно не согласен с тезисом. Я был бы счастлив, если бы stackoverflow превратился в ту базу знаний, которая предполагалась изначально, но, к сожалению, я вижу, что в таком случае как минимум исчезнет большая часть пользователей и следовательно у нас будет великолепная база знаний, которая, несмотря на все, перестанет попадать на первые страницы поисковиков просто из-за низкой активности ресурса

Comment: @EzikBro Почему большая часть пользователей должна исчезнуть? Не понимаю Ваше следствие. Прямо сейчас открыл топ участников и заметил, что из него всего несколько участвовали в конкурсах.

Comment: @nomnoms12 это следствие из того, какие в основном вопросы на основе - многие участники просто идут путем наименьшего сопротивления скидывая целые задания и просьбы на\дописать код, причем часто их задания гуглятся даже в тех же формулировках

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я правильно понял, что Вы поставили минус только из-за личной неприязни к автору и сходства с [соседним](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11150/339283) ответом? Простите, если задеваю Вас таким вопросом, но других аргументов не увидел, поэтому не до конца понимаю Вашу позицию.

Comment: @nomnoms12 думаю, EzikBro имеет в виду не только конкурсы. По моим субъективным ощущениям, где-то 95% вопросов на сайте — малополезный балласт, которые плохо сформулированы и плохо гуглятся (особенно касается старых вопросов с ХэшКода). Если их выпилить все к чертям, то оставшиеся 5% создадут великолепную базу знаний — но при этом сайт опустеет и приток новичков почти полностью остановится. Получается дилемма, когда сайту приходится балансировать между, скажем так, «сообществом» и «качеством» — и в общем-то допустимость/недопустимость (псевдо)конкурсов является частью этой дилеммы.

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, стало понятнее) Но мне кажется, что этот баланс и так предусмотрен в системе — Дух справляется со своими обязанностями. Я бы вообще ничего пока не менял. Лишь бы правил придерживались.

Comment: @nomnoms12, нет, вы не правильно поняли. У меня нет никакой личной неприязни к автору, и быть такого между участниками на SO, как мне думается, не должно. Мне кажется, я довольно понятно написал причину в комментарии, почему поставил минус. К тому же еще, написал ответ.

Comment: @andreymal, у меня тоже есть три минуса без возражений, так что тут мы в одинаковых условиях) И я не думаю, что это что-то значит... Просто на формулировку своих мыслей нужны силы и время и не все хотят, умеют и имеют возможность это сделать.

Comment: Обидно, что вопрос опять ушел в неконструктивное русло. Мне кажется, что для разрешения этой темы нужен какой-то непредвзятый посредник, который сможет немножко снизить накал страстей и доносить до обоих сторон точки зрения их оппонентов.

Comment: @МихаилРебров `Обидно, что вопрос опять ушел в неконструктивное русло`  То же самое и мне приходит в голову. И я понимаю причину эмоциональных срывов, когда один участник, в течение года, долбит и долбит **с упорством и произоводительностью перфоратора**, конкурсы анимаций и их участников в весьма нелицеприятной манере. Хорошая мысль - найти непредвзятого посредника в разрешении этой проблемы. Но опять же проблема, где найти такого участника, который одновременно был бы и непредвзятым и одновременно разбирался бы в анимациях SVG, CSS, JS и понимал бы, что можно, а что невозможно требовать

Comment: @andreymal, я написал Вам одно предложение в чат-комнате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116942/room-for---and-andreymal

Answer (score -1):

Не вижу смысла вновь поднимать эту тему. Смута всё это и ненужный холивар.

Вывод, который я сделал для себя, следующий:

- Вопросы, которые так сильно беспокоят некоторых участников, не
  являются спамом, не являются вредоносным кодом.
- Судя по количеству просмотров и рейтингу, они являются популярными и
  полезными.
- Следовательно, наша задача продолжать помогать новичкам в сфере
  программирования, делиться своим опытом между участниками, тем
  самым привнося сообществу пользу.
- Стараться не обращать внимание на различные провокации.

Всем желаю успехов!

Comment: Спасибо! Уважаю такую позицию.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor уважать ничем не обоснованную позицию — сомнительное занятие.

Comment: «и полезными» — это никак не следует из количества просмотров и рейтинга.

Comment: «наша задача продолжать помогать новичкам» — ну так и помогайте, это же здорово! Почему вместо настоящей помощи вы плодите бесполезные вопросы-свалки? Вы прикрываете свои псевдоконкурсы якобы помощью, а на самом деле вносите беспорядок (я описал в своём ответе, какой именно). Это лицемерие и вредительство.

Comment: (Справедливости ради, конкретно Sevastopol' и Alexandr_TT всё-таки обычно поясняют свой код, однако это не относится к другим отвечающим на псевдоконкурсах, так что в сумме всё равно выходит вредительство. Ну и не забываем, что код даже с пояснениями рискует утонуть в свалке из других ответов. Вопрос с самоответом — единственный правильный формат, чтобы поделиться своим опытом и принести **настоящую** пользу.)

Comment: @andreymal, если вам не нравится ответ, поставьте ему минус и объясните автору в комментарии, что именно ему стоит поправить

Comment: @avp я уже целых полгода занимаюсь объяснением этого...

Comment: @andreymal, на мете в своих темах или в комментариях авторам ответов с одним лишь кодом?

Comment: @avp такие ответы — следствие появления вопроса-свалки, поэтому и бороться нужно с причиной. Даже если я пройдусь и поставлю каждому ответу по минусу и комментарию, и даже если авторы ответов откликнутся и поправят (ха-ха) — от этого всё равно легче не станет (я разъяснил в своём ответе почему)

Comment: @andreymal, как можно с вами вести конструктивный диалог, если вы переходите на личности и открыто меня оскорбляете? А что касается полезности, то что означают стрелочки вверх/вниз, помните? Наведите, пожалуйста, на стрелки и почитайте подсказки.

Comment: @Sevastopol' а учитывая, что вы со своей дружной компанией решили напрочь игнорировать формат сайта, ваша отсылка к подсказкам на стрелочках выглядит ещё большим лицемерием — вряд ли людей, которые осознанно нарушают существующие правила, остановят какие-то там подсказки на стрелочках. Все мы с вами знаем, что плюсовать и минусовать могут и просто так по настроению.

Comment: @andreymal, увы, в противовес вам нечего сопоставить, поэтому вам и остается только меня оскорблять. Вы, Андрей, боритесь, как вам кажется, за соблюдение правил, при этом сами же нарушаете их. Правилами прямо запрещено оскорбление участников сообщества. Очень странно, почему модераторы не реагируют на такое поведение должным образом?

Comment: @Sevastopol' помните поговорку про бревно в глазу?