# Оскорбление участников в нашем сообществе это в порядке вещей. А-ля Доколе?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, оскорбление

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, почему некоторые участники позволяют себе оскорблять других участников сообщества и им за это ничего нет?

Например:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[*Комментарий к ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11152/377637)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[*Комментарий к ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11152/377637)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*[Ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/11137/1) на [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11134/377637)

---

Кто-то может ответить: ну так отмечайте такие комментарии тревогой. А в чем смысл этого? Ну отметил комментарии тревогой. Комментарии модераторы удалили. На этом месте снова появятся другие. Предлагаете снова отмечать их тревогой? Ну извините, простое удаление таких комментариев, содержащих оскорбление (а это умышленное унижение чести и достоинства личности), это прямая дорога к вседозволенности, которая ведет наше сообщество к бескультурщине, мату и сквернословию. Да, конечно, на эмоциях участник может не сдержаться и позволить себе грубость в отношении другого участника. Но насколько оскорбительна эта грубость, не сложно понимать и чётко для себя это осознавать. Очевидно, что это умышленные действия и полная уверенность в безнаказанности.

Comment: Я уже недавно просил себя забанить, но почему-то ничего не произошло. #модераторскийпроизвол

Comment: Хотя вообще «лицемер и вредитель» это просто констатация факта (и на одном из скриншотов это написано), а скриншотов реально оскорбительных комментариев почему-то нет.

Comment: `Предлагаете снова флагать?`, — я бы так и сделал. Остальное за модераторами, не зря же мы их выбирали. Тут по факту всего 3 оскорбления (2 от одного участника). Удаления достаточно, не помню, чтобы за такое сразу банили.

Comment: @nomnoms12 подобные высказывания от этого «одного участника» появляются систематически, одними лишь этими скриншотами это не ограничивается

Comment: @andreymal Совсем модераторы разленились получается :D #модераторскийпроизвол

Comment: @nomnoms12 так модераторы (некоторые) этим тоже страдают. Причём, судя по тому, что я вижу, с [прошлого раза](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1777/15479) ничего не поменялось. Я понимаю, что это такой характер, но такое не к лицу модератору.

Comment: Для успокоения участников дискуссии

Comment: @Barmaley, т.е. забанили и того кто уже 2 года терроризирует остальных участников, и того кто отбивается от этого участника культурными способами?!

Comment: @Barmaley т.е. теперь бан можно получить за жалобу на действия другого участника? Замечательный подход к модерации!

Comment: @Barmaley, а почему этот вопрос закрыли как «не по теме»? Почему он не по теме?

Comment: @Barmaley я думаю, что после прямых оскорблений других участников и вот таких банов всех подряд вам стоило бы сдать ромб.

Comment: Понимаю, что меня никто не слушает, тем не менее изложу свою точку зрения:
1) это не только мое решение, а коллегиальное решение нескольких модераторов. Забанены несколько участников дискуссии.
2) предлагается просто успокоиться - мы обязательно вернемся к дискуссии, решение сейчас вырабатывается в модераторском сообществе
3) это не бан (безусловно по форме бан), а просто способ успокоиться всем и нам и вам.

Comment: Как раз сейчас все успокоились и расслабились )

Comment: @HamSter <offtop>Разве я неадекватный или без рейтинга и годов (ну не так много тут, но и не мало)? Или мне не нужен руСО?</offtop>

Comment: @HamSter ;D да я шучу, просто я всегда думал, что я адекватный, но человек никогда не знает это про себя...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, извините "обычно я думаю нормально, а говорю .... " Не хотела обидеть!

Comment: После того, как я в очередной раз прочитал слово "флагать", меня вытошнило на клавиатуру.

Comment: Насколько я помню, слово "лицемер" считается оскорблением, а слово "вредитель" разрешено употреблять только модераторскому составу. Надо говорить так: "С сожалением должен констатировать факт, что Ваши возвышенные слова про помощь участникам сообщества по моим наблюдениям слабо соответствуют Вашим действиям разного рода, которые на протяжении долгого времени оцениваются многими участниками Stack Overflow на русском как не соответствующие духу правил и основополагающим принципам развития и пополнения базы знаний по программированию".

Comment: @Barmaley *Для успокоения участников дискуссии*. Нет лучшего способа завести любого, самого спокойного человека, чем сказать ему "успокойся!"...

Comment: @Igor, вы совершенно правы, я и сам не переношу это слово. Мало того, что такого слова не существует, оно и звучит некрасиво. Употребил его в тексте вопроса не более, чем как пример ранее данной мне рекомендации. Отредактировал вопрос, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Поздравляю всех причастных с тем, что при поиске слова «флагать» в результатах поиска на первой странице гугла и яндекса присутствует этот пост, вы внесли значимый вклад в развитие русского языка :)

Answer (score 19):

Такое поведение пользователей [абсолютно неприемлемо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

> Никаких резких замечаний или враждебно настроенных фраз.
> Какими бы ни были ваши намерения, подобное поведение может негативно отразиться на ваших коллегах.

> Сосредоточьтесь на содержимом, а не на личности. Не используйте слова, связанные с человеческими качествами (например, «ленивый»), даже если ими можно описать содержание сообщения.

Что делать?

Флагать. Также [можно связаться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) с администрацией, в частности, если вы считаете что действия модераторов некорректны или недостаточны.

Большое количество флагов на действия конкретного пользователя – основание для более активных мер.

ИМХО, как минимум, модераторам **уже давно стоит** в личных сообщениях напомнить некоторым конкретным пользователям о нормах поведения. А также прочитать их самим, просто чтобы не забывались.

Answer (score -2):

Не хотелось бы мне конечно вновь возвращаться к этому грязному делу. Но, прочитав [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11178/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment47650_11199) участника @Ипатьев...

> @VictorVosMottor а ты, я смотрю, тролляка первостатейный. То есть ты
> на StackOverflow ведешь политику "чем хуже тем лучше"? Ну-ну.
> Все-таки, лучшее, что может администрация - это разогнать всю вашу
> шушеру, а не играть с вами у кошки-мышки. 
> – Ипатьев

...ну очень захотелось об этом написать. А точнее даже спросить. У меня два вопроса:

1. Почему модераторами не принимаются никакие меры? Ну это же прямое оскорбление. Или мне просто показалось?
2. Почему модераторы не дают возможности участникам @VictorVosMottor и @Ипатьев успокоиться? Имеют место быть (как бы) [нападки в адрес друг друга](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11199/377637). Как [заметил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11156/ban-hammer-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-sevastopol#comment47549_11183) @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik:

> Оба из-за нападок в адрес друг друга. То, что в сообщениях не
> использовался мат, роли мало играет. Подобные конфликты в целом
> негативный фон повышают.

А для успокоения, кстати, у нас же появилась [новая форма наказания](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11178/377637). Или просто формулировка. Но это неважно, да?

К тому же, господин @Ипатьев сам призывал модераторов к более жесткому модерированию:

> Но на данный момент я считаю что модерирование на русо слишком мягкое,
> и особенно это касается горлопанов на мете.

Comment: Меня не за что банить.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, ну для успокоения участников дискуссии же)

Comment: @eanmos Я очень сильно успокоюсь. Настолько, что у кое-кого может и ромб полететь ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, это мы с вами знаем, что не за что. Но у кого-то на этот счет имеется другое мнение и веские основания для бана, формулировка которых звучит как музыка: `Для успокоения участников дискуссии`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor А каким способом может ромб полететь?

Comment: @SKIP 1. Сообщение на мете о раздаче банов не за что всем подряд (это у меня и так по плану, если эта фигня не прекратится) 2. Contact us форма: так и так модератор такой-то забанил меня и некоторых других людей по непонятной причине — в правилах ничего такого нет.

Answer (score -3):

[Напомню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4), что модераторы нашего сообщества должны, например:

- **подавать личный пример**,
- **демонстрировать уважение к другим участникам сообщества и на словах, и на деле**,

А вот [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11178/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment47698_11199) модератора Barmaley♦:

> Как ни странно, я двумя руками за данный ответ. Действительно, на мете
> встречаются отдельные персонажи, которые по своей сути являются
> троллями, но реального вклада в сообщество в виде правильных
> вопросов/ответов очень мало.

На [странице о выборах модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4) сказано, что *"модераторам сообщества предоставляется высочайший уровень привилегий в рамках сообщества, они в свою очередь, должны быть положительным примером и лидерами сообщества"*. Что идет вразрез с комментарием модератора Barmaley♦.

Как мне кажется, не совсем правильно относить участников, у которых возможно и мало вопросов/ответов, к такой категории, которая по своей сути является оскорбительной, унизительной. А также, наверное, не совсем правильно давать оценку участникам по количеству их вопросов/ответов, оценивать правильность их вопросов/ответов, судить о качестве реального вклада в сообщество.

---

На странице о выборах модераторов Barmaley♦ одним из пунктов в своей анкете указал:

> - человечность, для меня это важнее всего

А вот определение человечности - гуманизм, гуманность, человеческое отношение к окружающим. В общем смысле — система нравственных и социальных установок, предполагающая необходимость проявления сочувствия к людям, оказания помощи, не причинения страданий.

---

Вывод из всего этого каждый для себя пусть сделает сам.